# What is the most efficient, native way to image a Windows partition?

Tags: windows, dism, imaging, cloning, imagex

What is the most efficient, *native* way to image a Windows partition?

- Is the native method generally the best method for most users?
- How does the native method differ from conventional cloning?
- What are the pros and cons of native versus third-party tools?

How do I configure system partitions on a new drive for applying an image?

---

***Annotation:***

- *Many have taken issue with the "image" nomenclature, and it is the [correct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-reference--deployment-image-servicing-and-management) terminology*

  - *It's not up to an individual to change a developer's nomenclature since arbitrarily doing so would only sow confusion when referencing Windows' man pages [Microsoft Learn]*
- *While I can't definitively point to any specific Windows whitepaper, Windows' "image" nomenclature likely comes from how Windows is referred to from a servicing standpoint, which is as an "image", and is why `DISM` has the `/Online` and `/Image` [parameters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-operating-system-package-servicing-command-line-options):*

  - *Online image servicing deals with a `%SystemDrive%` while booted to it*
  - *Offline image servicing deals with a non-booted to `%SystemDrive%`*
  - *Image [management](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14) deals with the topic of this question*

---

Comment: _"Why is the native method generally the best method for most users?"_ - that's not really an honest, non-biased question.

Comment: @gronostaj More to the point, rather than what it isn't, we can say that it *is* a *[loaded question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loaded_question)*.

Comment: @gronostaj While I had in mind precisely what I wanted to address in the answer, the questions are both thoughtful & pertinent.

Comment: @J... As to loaded, not at all, as there's only one native way to image partitions in Windows for the last ~20yrs. I became exasperated continually addressing parts of these in comments and as answers on cloning issues questions, so I wanted to create a Q and A that addressed them in-depth, hoping to also squash misnomers & factually inaccurate info along the way _(appears to be harder than it really should be since many aren't bothering to read the source links)_.

Comment: @JW0914 All that's fine, but it's still a loaded question.  It presupposes that the native method is, in fact, generally the best method in asking why.

Comment: The question of how the OP defines efficiency comes to mind.  If your focused on speed you will choose no compression, but if you focused on image size you will choose max compression and slowest speed.  These are exclusive of each other you can not have the smallest image size at the fastest speed.  Also the question of time to actually image a computer comes up, which includes all setup time.  For example, If your an average user,who never installed sccm before, setting up SCCM that could take days to configure. Making a bootable clonezilla usb takes <1 hour.

Comment: @cybernard Imaging Windows to an SSD via `dism` with compression set to `max`/`recovery` has been faster in my experience than using `fast` with an HDD _(I cover this in the accepted answer)_. There is zero setup time for `dism`||`imagex`. No user will ever be using SCCM, which is now MEM, as the license alone is thousands of dollars - MEM, and its predecessor SCCM, are only for businesses managing hundreds to thousands of machines and OEMs, as installing and imaging is done via LTI/ZTI Task Sequences like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9l5c.png). Clonezilla isn't a native Windows solution.

Comment: You can't compare a SSD to an HDD.  If I use fast compression with an SSD its even faster than max/recovery on a SSD.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> ### *What is the most efficient, native way to image a Windows partition?*

For the majority of users, capturing an image of a partition via [**`DISM`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14) *(XP ≤ 7: [`ImageX`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749447(v=ws.10).aspx))* is *generally* the best and most efficient method, while also not causing the common configuration issues with third-party tools or *Windows Image Backup* and *Backup and Restore (Windows 7)*

- Win XP ≥ 10 has *always* natively supported imaging of partitions and filesystems:

  - Imaging the OS partition is slightly different than other partitions, as it can only be imaged from WinPE/WinRE
  - Microsoft's [Windows Imaging File Format](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13096) whitepaper explains the WIM format

    - WIMs [**W**indows **IM**age] can capture an entire partition or individual folders/files
    - ESDs [**E**ncrypted **S**oftware **D**istribution] can only capture an OS partition and must use  `/Compress:Recovery` *(algorithm is ~33% more efficient than `/Compress:Max`)*

      - Windows ≥ 10: Can only be used for PBR [[**P**ush-**B**utton **R**eset](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/push-button-reset-overview)] exported images 
         Windows ≤ 8.1: Only a bootable Windows install can be captured as an ESD
- All WinPE/WinRE [WIMs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/wim-vs-ffu-image-file-formats) have `DISM` included within them *(Win XP ≤ 7: `ImageX`)*:

  - **WinPE:** **Win**dows **P**reinstallation **E**nvironment 
     *(Windows Setup boot media: **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>** to access terminal)*
  - **WinRE:** **Win**dows **R**ecovery **E**nvironment 
     *(WinRE is a WinPE image containing extra [WinPE Optional Components](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-add-packages--optional-components-reference) vital to recovery)*

    ```powershell
    # Once booted to WinRE: Advanced → Troubleshoot → Command Prompt

    # To boot to WinRE:
      Shutdown /f /r /o /t 0
    ```

---

***Annotation:***

- *Many have taken issue with the "image" nomenclature, and it is the [correct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-reference--deployment-image-servicing-and-management) terminology*

  - *It's not up to an individual to change a developer's nomenclature since arbitrarily doing so would only sow confusion when referencing Windows' man pages [Microsoft Learn]*
- *While I can't definitively point to any specific Windows whitepaper, Windows' "image" nomenclature likely comes from how Windows is referred to from a servicing standpoint, which is as an "image", and is why `DISM` has the `/Online` and `/Image` [parameters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-operating-system-package-servicing-command-line-options):*

  - *Online image servicing deals with a `%SystemDrive%` while booted to it*
  - *Offline image servicing deals with a non-booted to `%SystemDrive%`*
  - *Image [management](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14) deals with the topic of this answer*

---

#### Imaging

<sub>*[(Powershell cmdlet)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/use-dism-in-windows-powershell-s14)*</sub>

Specify exclusions or exceptions by creating a [**`WimScript.ini`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-configuration-list-and-wimscriptini-files-winnext) config file, with `/ScratchDir` being required in WinPE since it only has 32MB of scratch [temp] space by default:

- Even though `/CheckIntegrity` *(`ImageX`: `/Check`)* and `Verify` extend processing time, they should always be used since they prevent corruption from occurring within the WIM/ESD

1. **Either *Capture* or *Append* an image:**

   - **[Capture Image](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#capture-image):**

     ```powershell
     # Windows ≥8: DISM
       Dism /Capture-Image /ImageFile:"Z:\Base.wim" /CaptureDir:"C:" /Name:"Windows Backup" /Description:"Base Image 2020.08.29 @ 11:30" /Compress:Max /CheckIntegrity /Verify /ScratchDir:"Z:"

     # Windows XP ≤ 7: ImageX
       ImageX /Capture "C:" "Z:\Base.esd" "Windows Backup" "Base Image 2020.08.29 @ 11:30" /Compress:Recovery /Check /Verify /ScratchDir:"Z:\"
     ```

     - If saving the image to a mechanical HDD, compression takes longer, so if wanting to use `/Compress:Max` or `/Compress:Recovery` and time is an issue, it'll be more efficient to use `/Compress:Fast`, [exporting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#export-image) the image later using *Max* or *Recovery*
     - For managing size constraints, images can be split into multiple read-only `.swm` files via [**`/Split-Image`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#split-image)
   - **[Append Image](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#append-image):**

     ```powershell
     # Windows ≥8: DISM
       Dism /Append-Image /ImageFile:"Z:\Base.wim" /CaptureDir:"C:" /Name:"Windows Backup" /Description:"Base Image 2020.08.29 @ 11:30" /CheckIntegrity /Verify /ScratchDir:"Z:"

     # Windows XP ≤ 7: ImageX
       ImageX /Append "C:" "Z:\Base.esd" "Windows Backup" "Base Image 2020.08.29 @ 11:30" /Compress:Recovery /Check /Verify /ScratchDir:"Z:\"
     ```

     - Compression is locked to the value set when the base image was captured
     - Individual indexes can be deleted via [**`/Delete-Image`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#delete-image) or exported to their own image via [**`/Export-Image`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#export-image)
2. **[Apply Image](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#apply-image):**

   ```powershell
   # Windows ≥8: DISM
     Dism /Apply-Image /ImageFile:"Z:\Base.wim" /Index:1 /ApplyDir:"C:" /CheckIntegrity /Verify /ScratchDir:"Z:"

   # Windows XP ≤ 7: ImageX
     ImageX /Apply "Z:\Base.wim" 1 "C:" /Check /Verify /ScratchDir:"Z:\"
   ```

   - Prior to applying, get [Image Info](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#get-imageinfo), ensuring correct index [image] is being applied:

     ```bash
     Dism /Get-ImageInfo /ImageFile:"Z:\Base.wim"
     ```
   - If applying an OS image, the following must be run prior to exiting WinPE/WinRE:

     - BIOS:

       ```powershell
       BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /FixBoot && BootRec /RebuildBCD
       ```
     - UEFI:

       ```powershell
       ::# With existing bootable EFI partition:
           BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /RebuildBCD


       ::# Without existing bootable EFI partition:
           ::# Create EFI directories and enter:
               MkDir "Y:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot"
               Cd /d "Y:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot"

           ::# Create EFI boot structure:
               BootRec /Fixboot

               ::# If Access Denied error occurs (C: is applied image):
                   BcdBoot C:\Windows /s Y: /f UEFI

           ::# Resolve any other boot issues:
               BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /RebuildBCD
       ```

#### Accessing data within a WIM or ESD

1. **Read-only:**

   1. **[Mount Image](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#mount-image):** *(as `/ReadOnly`)*

      ```powershell
      # Windows ≥8: DISM
        Dism /Mount-Image /ImageFile:"Z:\Base.wim" /Index:2 /MountDir:"C:\Mount" /Optimize /CheckIntegrity /ReadOnly

      # Windows XP ≤ 7: ImageX
        ImageX /Mount "Z:\Base.wim" 2 "C:\Mount" /Check
      ```

      - *In lieu of this, I prefer opening the `.wim`/`.esd` within the [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) GUI*
   2. **[Unmount Image](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#unmount-image):** *(`/discard` changes)*

      ```powershell
      # Windows ≥8: DISM
        Dism /Unmount-Image /MountDir:"C:\Mount" /CheckIntegrity /Discard

      # Windows XP ≤ 7: ImageX
        ImageX /Unmount "C:\Mount"
      ```
2. **Make changes, or add data, to an image [index]:**

   1. **Mount Image:**

      ```powershell
      # Windows ≥8: DISM
        Dism /Mount-Image /ImageFile:"Z:\Base.wim" /Index:2 /MountDir:"C:\Mount" /Optimize /CheckIntegrity

      # Windows XP ≤ 7: ImageX
        ImageX /MountRW "Z:\Base.wim" 2 "C:\Mount" /Check
      ```
   2. **Unmount Image:** *(`/Commit` changes)*

      ```powershell
      # Windows ≥8: DISM
        Dism /Unmount-Image /MountDir:"C:\Mount" /CheckIntegrity /Commit

      # Windows XP ≤ 7: ImageX
        ImageX /Unmount "C:\Mount" /Commit
      ```

      - If using `DISM`, to save changes as a new appended image, add `/Append`

---

> ### *Is the native method generally the best method for most users?*

- With the native method [WIMs/ESDs], no additional imaging tools or boot media is required since support is natively built-in to WinPE and Windows
- Its *impossible* for WIMs/ESDs to become corrupted, provided `/CheckIntegrity` *(`ImageX`: `/Check`)* & `/Verify` are *always* used
- Capturing and applying a `.wim`/`.esd` is not the best solution for all imaging [cloning] use cases, but is for most:

  - Capturing a `.wim`/`.esd` requires a storage medium to house the captured image *(partition not being imaged, USB drive, network share, etc.)*, serving the dual purpose of also being an actual backup base image
  - Additional backups of the *same partition* can be appended to the base image with minimal [relative] file size increase, and while data from multiple partitions can be appended to the same base image, the smart compression feature benefits WIMs provide would be lost
- WIMs/ESDs are [smart compression image formats](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13096) and therefore storage efficient:

  - Only changed files are added to a `.wim`/`.esd` when a new image [index] is appended to it; newly appended images utilize the same copy of unchanged files already contained within the image from the previous image(s) *[(hash verified)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13096)*, allowing for an image to remain small in relation to the data within 
     Appended image example:

    ```powershell
    # Note Base.wim size compared to each index and sum of all data therein:

      PS $  ls -File

        Length           Name
        ---------------  -------------
        95,019,530,773B  Base.wim
                   568B  Dism.cmd
                    97B  WimScript.ini


      PS $  Dism /Get-ImageInfo /ImageFile:Base.wim

        Details for image : Base.wim

        Index : 1
          Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
          Description : v1803: Base (Drivers Only)
          Size : 22,710,283,446 bytes

        Index : 2
          Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
          Description : v1803: Software Installed (No Customizations)
          Size : 45,591,850,754 bytes

        Index : 3
          Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
          Description : v1803: Software Installed (Customized)
          Size : 94,958,267,312 bytes

        Index : 4
          Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
          Description : v1809: Updated Applications
          Size : 114,959,954,040 bytes
    ```

    ```powershell
    PS $  Dism /Get-ImageInfo /ImageFile:Base.wim /Index:1

      Details for image : Base.wim

        Index : 1
        Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
        Description : v1803: Base (Drivers Only)
        Size : 22,710,283,446 bytes
        WIM Bootable : No
        Architecture : x64
        Hal : acpiapic
        Version : 10.0.17134
        ServicePack Build : 1
        ServicePack Level : 1
        Edition : Professional
        Installation : Client
        ProductType : WinNT
        ProductSuite : Terminal Server
        System Root : WINDOWS
        Directories : 24288
        Files : 112665
        Created : 2018.05.05 - 13:56:47
        Modified : 2018.05.05 - 13:56:47
        Languages : en-US (Default)


    PS $  Dism /Get-ImageInfo /ImageFile:Base.wim /Index:2

      Details for image : Base.wim

        Index : 2
        Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
        Description : v1803: Software Installed (No Customizations)
        Size : 45,591,850,754 bytes
        WIM Bootable : No
        Architecture : x64
        Hal : acpiapic
        Version : 10.0.17134
        ServicePack Build : 1
        ServicePack Level : 1
        Edition : Professional
        Installation : Client
        ProductType : WinNT
        ProductSuite : Terminal Server
        System Root : WINDOWS
        Directories : 45803
        Files : 203058
        Created : 2018.05.06 - 01:55:47
        Modified : 2018.05.06 - 01:55:48
        Languages : en-US (Default)


    PS $  Dism /Get-ImageInfo /ImageFile:Base.wim /Index:3

      Details for image : Base.wim

        Index : 3
        Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
        Description : v1803: Software Installed (Customized)
        Size : 94,958,267,312 bytes
        WIM Bootable : No
        Architecture : x64
        Hal : acpiapic
        Version : 10.0.17134
        ServicePack Build : 1
        ServicePack Level : 81
        Edition : Professional
        Installation : Client
        ProductType : WinNT
        ProductSuite : Terminal Server
        System Root : WINDOWS
        Directories : 62409
        Files : 350446
        Created : 2018.06.01 - 19:09:51
        Modified : 2018.06.19 - 21:26:18
        Languages : en-US (Default)


    PS $  Dism /Get-ImageInfo /ImageFile:Base.wim /Index:4

      Details for image : Base.wim

        Index : 4
        Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
        Description : v1809: Updated Applications
        Size : 114,959,954,040 bytes
        WIM Bootable : No
        Architecture : x64
        Hal : acpiapic
        Version : 10.0.17763
        ServicePack Build : 195
        ServicePack Level : 0
        Edition : Professional
        Installation : Client
        ProductType : WinNT
        ProductSuite : Terminal Server
        System Root : WINDOWS
        Directories : 87659
        Files : 452028
        Created : 2018.12.24 - 04:27:13
        Modified : 2018.12.24 - 04:27:15
        Languages : en-US (Default)
    ```
- In contrast to WIMs/ESDs, *Windows Image Backup* and *Backup and Restore (Windows 7)* create a VHD image while booted to the OS using the Volume Shadow Copy Service [VSS], being no different than creating a VHD and using `RoboCopy` to copy all data, maintaining ACLs, to the VHD from the OS partition, and has:

  - little to no compression *(storage inefficient)*
  - no parity *(lacks data verification)*
  - total reliance on a myriad of external config, catalog, and binary files residing outside of the VHD to work correctly *(in contrast to a self-contained WIM/ESD image)*, and if these become corrupted/modified or moved/deleted, a restore isn't possible and will fail:

    ```ini
    # VM: EFI boot with clean install of Windows 11
      # Note VHD size versus ESD/WIM images of the same VM:
        # VHD (20.76GB)
        # WIM (9.23GB)
        # ESD (6.92GB)


    PS $ ls -file

      Length           Name
      ---------------  -------------
      20,761,804,800B  87a69c87-81dd-4b7f-95a1-1bff3144b638.vhdx
      6,921,506,902B   vm.esd
      9,238,800,695B   vm.wim


    PS $ tree -f

      | MediaID.bin
      | vm.esd
      | vm.wim
      |
      └─VM
        │ MediaID.bin
        |
        └─Backup Set 2024-03-19 060426
          ├─Backup Files 2024-03-19 060426
          │  Backup files 1.zip
          │  Backup files 2.zip
          │  Backup files 3.zip
          │  Backup files 4.zip
          │  Backup files 5.zip
          │  Backup files 6.zip
          │  Backup files 7.zip
          │  Backup files 8.zip
          │  Backup files 9.zip
          │  Backup files 10.zip
          │  Backup files 11.zip
          │  Backup files 12.zip
          │  Backup files 13.zip
          │  Backup files 14.zip
          │  Backup files 15.zip
          │  Backup files 16.zip
          │  Backup files 17.zip
          │  Backup files 18.zip
          │  Backup files 19.zip
          │  Backup files 20.zip
          │  Backup files 21.zip
          │  Backup files 22.zip
          │  Backup files 23.zip
          │  Backup files 24.zip
          │  Backup files 25.zip
          │  Backup files 26.zip
          │  Backup files 27.zip
          │  Backup files 28.zip
          │  Backup files 29.zip
          │  Backup files 30.zip
          |
          ├─Catalogs
          │  GlobalCatalog.wbcat
      |
      └─WindowsImageBackup
        └─VM
          │ MediaId
          |
          ├─Backup 2024-03-19 130431
          │  127dbd44-5431-4b1c-9500-426293266794.vhdx
          │  87a69c87-81dd-4b7f-95a1-1bff3144b638.vhdx
          │  BackupSpecs.xml
          │  Esp.vhdx
          │  f714635b-5a6a-4163-9695-33ae3fa712a6_AdditionalFilesc3b9f3c7-5e52-4d5e-8b20-19adc95a34c7.xml
          │  f714635b-5a6a-4163-9695-33ae3fa712a6_Components.xml
          │  f714635b-5a6a-4163-9695-33ae3fa712a6_RegistryExcludes.xml
          │  f714635b-5a6a-4163-9695-33ae3fa712a6_Writer4dc3bdd4-ab48-4d07-adb0-3bee2926fd7f.xml
          │  f714635b-5a6a-4163-9695-33ae3fa712a6_Writer542da469-d3e1-473c-9f4f-7847f01fc64f.xml
          │  f714635b-5a6a-4163-9695-33ae3fa712a6_Writera6ad56c2-b509-4e6c-bb19-49d8f43532f0.xml
          │  f714635b-5a6a-4163-9695-33ae3fa712a6_Writerafbab4a2-367d-4d15-a586-71dbb18f8485.xml
          │  f714635b-5a6a-4163-9695-33ae3fa712a6_Writerbe000cbe-11fe-4426-9c58-531aa6355fc4.xml
          │  f714635b-5a6a-4163-9695-33ae3fa712a6_Writercd3f2362-8bef-46c7-9181-d62844cdc0b2.xml
          │  f714635b-5a6a-4163-9695-33ae3fa712a6_Writere8132975-6f93-4464-a53e-1050253ae220.xml
          |
          ├─Catalog
          │  BackupGlobalCatalog
          │  GlobalCatalog
          |
          ├─Logs
          |
          ├─SPPMetadataCache
          │  {f714635b-5a6a-4163-9695-33ae3fa712a6}
    ```

---

> ### *How does the native method differ from conventional cloning?*

The vast majority of Windows users have no need for partition-level or disk-level images:

- A conventional partition-level or disk-level image *(contains offset, alignment, block size, etc.)*:

  - Lacks native Windows support and therefore requires non-standard boot media *(boot media that's not WinPE/WinRE)* and third-party programs
  - Often lacks compression by default, one of the main advantages of the WIM/ESD [smart compression image format](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13096)
  - Locks the user to that specific partition or drive layout *(offset, alignment, block size, etc.)*
  - Often has no data verification and is therefore subject to data corruption
- `DISM`/`ImageX` creates a filesystem image, not a partition partition-level or disk-level image: 
   *(Win ≥ XP uses NTFS as the default filesystem)*

  - When pointed at the root of a partition [`C:\`], `DISM`/`ImageX` captures an image of all data on that partition, but not the structure of the partition/drive itself *(offset, alignment, block size, etc.)*, bypassing the inconvenience a conventional partition/drive image creates, as only filesystem data is contained within a `.wim`/`.esd`, allowing it to be applied to any partition, regardless of size difference or whether there is existing data on the partition.

---

> ### *What are the pros and cons of native versus 3rd party?*

Third-party tools will almost always fall into one of two categories, Linux-based or Windows-based via `DISM`/`ImageX`/`Powershell`, with many resulting in configuration issues, and the latter sometimes encompassing developers who use proprietary image file formats and custom boot environments *(many of which are Linux-based)*.

- There's a minute number of posts on StackExchange *(or [Spiceworks](https://community.spiceworks.com/))* regarding imaging issues arising from using Windows' native `DISM` *(Win XP ≤ 7: `ImageX`)*, however thousands of questions, answers, and comments exist for issues arising from third-party imaging tools:

  - [Windows cloning issue](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=Windows%20cloning%20issue) *(2,751 results)* 
     [Windows cloning problem](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=Windows%20cloning%20problem) *(3,838 results)*
  - `DISM`:

    - [Windows `Dism /Capture-Image` issue](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=Windows%20Dism%20%2FCapture-Image%20issue) *(60 results)* 
       [Windows `Dism /Capture-Image` problem](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=Windows%20Dism%20%2FCapture-Image%20problem) *(44 results)*
    - [Windows `Dism /Append-Image` issue](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=Windows%20Dism%20%2FAppend-Image%20issue) *(20 results)* 
       [Windows `Dism /Append-Image` problem](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=Windows%20Dism%20%2FAppend-Image%20problem) *(12 results)*
    - [Windows `Dism /Apply-Image` issue](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=Windows%20Dism%20%2FApply-Image%20issue) *(85 results)* 
       [Windows `Dism /Apply-Image` problem](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=Windows%20Dism%20%2FApply-Image%20problem) *(93 results)*
  - `ImageX`:

    - [Windows `ImageX /Capture` issue](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=Windows%20ImageX%20%2FCapture%20issue) *(19 results)* 
       [Windows `ImageX /Capture` problem](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=Windows%20ImageX%20%2FCapture%20problem) *(20 results)*
    - [Windows `ImageX /Append` issue](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=Windows%20ImageX%20%2FAppend%20issue) *(10 results)* 
       [Windows `ImageX /Append` problem](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=Windows%20ImageX%20%2FAppend%20problem) *(5 results)*
    - [Windows `ImageX /Apply` issue](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=Windows%20ImageX%20%2FApply%20issue) *(15 results)* 
       [Windows `ImageX /Apply` problem](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=Windows%20ImageX%20%2FApply%20problem) *(12 results)*
- *I have the perspective it's unacceptable for a Windows user to receive advice to use Linux tools to image Windows, as that's inefficient, forcing the user to rely on not only a non-native boot environment unsupported by Windows, but also on an image format unsupported by Windows, both of which over-complicate imaging. 

   Ever come across advice telling a BSD or Linux user to boot to Windows or use [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) to back up their data? For example, `ntfsclone` (part of `ntfs-3g`) is a popular Linux utility, with the following from it's [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfsclone):*

  > ***Windows Cloning** 
  >
  >  If you want to copy, move or restore a system or boot partition to another computer, to a different disk, partition... or to a different disk sector offset, then you will need to take extra care. 
  >
  >  **Usually, Windows will not be able to boot**, unless you copy, move or restore NTFS to the same partition which starts at the same sector on the same type of disk having the same BIOS legacy cylinder setting as the original partition and disk had. 
  >
  >  The `ntfsclone` utility guarantees to make an exact copy of NTFS, but it won't deal with booting issues. This is by design: `ntfsclone` is a filesystem, not system utility; its aim is only NTFS cloning, **not Windows cloning**. Hereby `ntfsclone` can be used as a very fast and reliable build block for Windows cloning but [it] itself it's not enough.*

WIMs/ESDs don't have these issues since they only contain filesystem information *(files and directories)*, not partition/drive level data, allowing them to be applied to any partition, regardless of size difference or whether there is existing data.

#### Native Pros

- WIMs/ESDs are natively supported by all Windows editions ≥ XP

  - WIMs/ESDs are versatile and can be captured, applied, or modified when booted to WinPE *(Windows install media)*, WinRE *(Windows Recovery)*, or the OS
  - WIMs/ESDs do not require additional tools or boot media since all required tools are built-in to all three environments
- WIMs/ESDs are [smart compression image formats](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13096), able to contain multiple images, backups or otherwise, within a relatively small single image file
- Its *impossible* for WIMs/ESDs to become corrupted, provided `/CheckIntegrity` *(`ImageX`: `/Check`)* & `/Verify` are *always* used
- WIMs/ESDs can be deployed remotely via PXE, even to a machine without an OS installed

#### Native Cons

- Requires a storage medium for the captured image *(another partition, USB drive, network share, etc.)*

  - If saving the image to a mechanical HDD, compression takes longer, so if wanting to use `/Compress:Max` or `/Compress:Recovery`, it's more efficient to use `/Compress:Fast`, [exporting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#export-image) the image later using `Max` or `Recovery`
- Capturing, Appending, Applying, or Exporting an image is resource-intensive

  - Even though `/CheckIntegrity` *(`ImageX`: `/Check`)* and `Verify` do extend the image processing time, they should *always* be used

---

> ### *How do I configure system partitions on a new drive for applying an image?*

1. **Use [`DiskPart`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/diskpart):**

   ```powershell
   DiskPart

   ::# List disks:
       Lis Dis

   ::# Select OS drive # the image is being applied to:
       Sel Dis #

   ::# Wipe partition table (assumes no data on drive is being preserved)
       Clean
   ```

   **UEFI:**

   ```powershell
   Convert gpt
   ```
2. **Create boot partition:**

   - **BIOS:**

     ```powershell
     Cre Par Pri Offset=1024 Size=100
     Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label="Boot"
     Active
     ```
   - **UEFI:**

     ```powershell
     Cre Par EFI Offset=1024 Size=100
     Format Quick Fs=FAT32 Label="EFI"
     Assign Letter=Y
     Cre Par Msr Size=16
     ```
3. **Create OS partition:**

   - **Rest of the drive as the OS partition:** 
      *If `C:` can't be assigned, change 3 & 5 to another letter* 
      **BIOS:**

     ```powershell
     Cre Par Pri
     Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label="System"
     ```

     **UEFI:**

     ```powershell
     Cre Par Pri Id=ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7
     Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label="System"
     Assign Letter=C
     ```
   - **Additional partitions after the [200GB] OS partition:** 
      *If storing User Data directories on a partition other than `C:\` (recommended), max size required is ~300GB* *(multiply size wanted by 1024: `200*1024=204800`)* 
      **BIOS:**

     ```powershell
     Cre Par Pri Size=204800
     Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label="System"
     ```

     **UEFI:**

     ```powershell
     Cre Par Pri Size=204800 Id=ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7
     Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label="System"
     Assign Letter=C
     ```
4. **Create WinRE partition:** *(should have 320MB free to allow for future WIM size increases)*

   - **BIOS:**

     ```powershell
     Shrink Desired=665 Minimum=650
     Cre Par Pri id=27
     Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label="WinRE"
     ```
   - **UEFI:**

     ```powershell
     Shrink Desired=665 Minimum=650
     Cre Par Pri Id=de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac
     Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label="WinRE"
     Gpt Attributes=0x8000000000000001
     ```
5. **Resolve any boot issues:** *(once system image has been applied)*

   - **BIOS:**

     ```powershell
     BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /FixBoot && BootRec /RebuildBCD
     ```
   - **UEFI:**

     ```powershell
     ::# With existing bootable EFI partition:
         BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /RebuildBCD


     ::# Without existing bootable EFI partition:
       ::# Create EFI directories and enter:
           MkDir "Y:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot"
           Cd /d "Y:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot"

       ::# Create EFI boot structure:
           BootRec /Fixboot

           ::# If Access Denied error occurs (C: is applied image):
               BcdBoot C:\Windows /s Y: /f UEFI

       ::# Resolve any other boot issues:
           BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /RebuildBCD
     ```
6. **Remove EFI mountpoint *(if applicable)* and Reboot 
    UEFI:**

   ```powershell
   DiskPart

     Sel Vol Y
     Remove
     Exit
   ```

Comment: "Windows has always natively supported imaging of partitions or individual directories" is vast hyperbole.  Windows was around *long* before Longhorn/Vista (which introduced ImageX, the predecessor to `dism`).  Further, neither ImageX nor `dism`meets the Question's demand for a "native way to image a Windows partition", since both image the filesystem on a partition.  This is not merely semantics.

Comment: @EricTowers Thing is, many Windows users tend to say "partition" when they actually mean "filesystem", which stems from lots of Windows software and documentation confusing the two terms in many places.

Comment: @EricTowers How is that hyperbole? You do know Windows is installed via a WIM or ESD image, as well as deployed via MDT or SCCM right? _(Did you by chance check out the linked to whitepaper explaining the technical aspects of the WIM format?)_ `ImageX` isn't a predecessor to `DISM` in the normal sense, as they're OS-specific _(`ImageX` cannot be used to image a system partition on Win ≥8 and `DISM` cannot be used to image on Win ≤7)_. If a WIM or ESD is not a "native way to image a Windows partition", then what exactly do you believe it is _(please reference the appended image example above)_?

Comment: @JW0914 : "**always**", emphasis mine, is incorrect, as is your claim "Windows is installed via a WIM or ESD image".  Windows 1, 2, 3.0-WfW 3.12, NT 3.5.0-4.1, 95, 98, 98SE all precede WIM, ESD, ImageX, and `dism`.  I still install Win98SE from time to time; it, like many of the Windows I listed, is installed from CAB files.  The WIM/ESD/ImageX/`dism` ecosystem didn't exist prior to Longhorn/Vista and I note that the Question doesn't specify a version or range of versions of Windows in text or in tags, so you have, at best, given a partial answer, incorrectly claiming universal scope.

Comment: @EricTowers Why would an answer in 2020 address OS versions more than two decades old?  `ImageX` is included in all Windows versions  ≥XP _(which is specified in the answer, however I do understand your point and will edit accordingly)_, with all versions ≥7 using an `install.esd`/`install.wim`. Too many have confused what imaging a partition on BSD/Linux is versus natively imaging a partition on Windows, as these are not the same. For the majority of Windows users, imaging data at the partition-level or disk-level serves zero purpose, introducing several inconveniences along the way.

Comment: I think you have the HDD vs. SSD compression thing backwards. On HDDs the disk becomes a bottleneck, so you could want to _increase_ compression: the less data to write, the sooner it will be done and you have extra CPU time anyway due to disk's slowness. For SSDs faster compression could be preferred, otherwise the CPU may not keep up with delivering data to write. In the end it's a matter of balancing CPU vs. disk usage to keep them both as busy as possible, but the faster the disk, the faster compression you need if you want to optimize for fastest imaging.

Comment: _"Why would an answer in 2020 address OS versions more than two decades old?"_ - you don't have to address them. Just don't pretend they don't exist. Facts don't expire, and "always" implies there are no exceptions.

Comment: @gronostaj I understood the point Eric was making and edited accordingly. `/Compress:Fast` was recommended if time is a constraint when saving the captured image to a mechanical HDD, lessening the time it takes for image capturing - `/Compress:Max`|`/Compress:Recovery` for a100GB+ system partition often takes several hours versus the 30m - 60m with a SATA III SSD. I recommend `Max`||`Recovery` for all use cases, however if a user doesn't have several hours to wait in WinPE/WinRE, using `/Compress:Fast`, then exporting to `Compress:Max` [WIM] or `/Compress:Recovery` [ESD], would be recommended.

Comment: It seems pretty misleading to call the stuff described in this answer an "image" at all. It's a file archive created by means of copying the files into a completely different filesystem, and nothing is ever imaged.

Comment: @hobbs If you have an issue with the nomenclature, take it up with Microsoft, as this is how you image Windows and has been the way for ~20yrs. Might I suggest actually reading at least a few of the 24 source links, of which explain in more detail, however this is not a Q and A about what any one person's _opinion_ of what constitutes an "image" is, but how to capture partition images natively in Windows... the commands used should imply this, considering they have the word _image_ in them after all, but hey, I only linked to Microsoft Docs and technical articles 21 times, so what do I know.

Comment: MS being flat out wrong in word usage is definitely nothing new, and goes back more than 20 years :)

Comment: WIM is indeed not a disk image in the traditional sense, even if Microsoft insists on calling it so. A "disk image" usually means a sector-by-sector dump or a sparse equivalent, where "sparse" means lacking sectors that don't contain useful data according to FS. WIM is, [as admitted by Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/wim-vs-ffu-image-file-formats) file-based, so it's not an image in this traditional sense. This is confirmed by ability to create a WIM only from selected path or to exclude certain files, which would not be possible with an image.

Comment: @gronostaj Per Microsoft Docs _(Microsoft's man pages)_, which I reference >20x with source links, a WIM/ESD is an image. As stated above, if users take issue with the nomenclature, take it up with Microsoft, as I'm not here to debate what users consider the definition of a partition image to be. Microsoft is the developer of Windows and they've referred to WIMs/ESDs as images for over two decades,since Win XP _(the definition of an image is not the same between Windows and BSD/Linux)_. Perhaps users could take a portion of the 30hrs I spent on this answer and actually read the source links.

Comment: I don't think it's okay to incorrectly call it an image because Microsoft has been incorrectly calling it an image for years. It's still not an image and calling it so will only cause confusion. Microsoft is wrong when they use this term for WIMs and we are wrong when we're repeating after them. I appreciate your effort - I have this question bookmarked for future use and I've linked it in my answers - but linking to 30 articles that use nomenclature that we've established is misleading doesn't justify repeating that mistake.

Comment: @gronostaj I understand the point you're making, however for Windows "image" is the correct terminology per the developer. If I was to arbitrarily and individually change the nomenclature that would only sow more confusion when referencing Microsoft Docs. It's not up to an individual to change a developer's nomenclature, incorrect as it may be, as that has to come from the developer _(it's more than just Windows, as MDT and [SCCM](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center) / [MECM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/) are built upon Microsoft's "image" nomenclature)_.

Comment: @gronostaj While I can't definitively point to any specific Windows documentation/whitepaper, Microsoft's "image" nomenclature likely comes from how Windows is referred to from a servicing standpoint, which is as an "image" _(i.e. online image servicing, referring to servicing the `%SystemDrive%` while booted to it, whereas offline image servicing refers to servicing a non-booted to `%SystemDrive%`, such as from WinPE/WinRE, and is why `DISM` has the `/Online` and `/Image` parameters - e.g. `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` or `Dism /Image:D:\Windows /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`)_

Comment: @JW0914 - Great write up.. I read a lot of that for few months in 2016 and wish your answer had been available at the time :) . PS: Quick question - Do any 3rd party tools/ companies also use/ support WIM format? Since VHD (sector based) is commonly supported by most.

Comment: @AlexS Since the WIM format was developed by Microsoft, the code is likely proprietary, so I've never come across a third-party that uses the format outside of using it with `Dism`/`ImageX` within WinPE.

Comment: Hmm. I’d think some tools would support format under its management framework given they can be zip opened. Are there any other non sector / file based formats other than WIM?

Comment: @AlexS WIMs/ESDs can't be zip opened, but can via 7zip since they're an archive file format, however they can't be modified in 7zip _(modifying a WIM/ESD without using `Dism`/`ImageX` would cause irreparable image corruption)_. [This](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13096) technical whitepaper explains the WIM/ESD format, as they are complex with built-in parity; AFAIK, no 3rd-party uses them except for imaging Windows partitions, but you may want to ask that on [Spiceworks](https://community.spiceworks.com/) since Microsoft has vendor reps that monitor the forum.

Comment: @JW0914 - True. Long time since posting on SW - will ask over there :)

Comment: @AlexS: [wimlib](https://wimlib.net/) allow read/write access to WIM —and probably ESD— archives since about [2013](http://reboot.pro/index.php?showtopic=18345); interoperability with Microsoft (_"native"_) tools is not perfect, so as always please backup first, but it can achieve useful things.

Comment: @AntoineL [Image management](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14) is one function of `Dism`, with `Dism` having multiple additional functions off topic to this question and answer _(e.g. I cover another functionality of `Dism` [here](https://superuser.com/q/1579030/529800))_. The acronym stands for **D**eployment **I**mage **S**ervicing and **M**anagement and is how Windows is [serviced](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/what-is-dism?view=windows-11) online or offline.

Comment: @AntoineL `Dism` is for imaging Windows ≥8, whereas `ImageX` is required for imaging Windows XP ≤ 7, as `Dism` gained that feature when Microsoft depreciated `ImageX` in Windows 8 _(prior to this, it was used for servicing the OS)_ - `ImageX` cannot be used to image Windows in ≥8 and `Dism` can't be used to image in XP ≤ 7. Both tools are included in the WinPE/WinRE images of the respective OS version. Standalone `Dism`/`ImageX` version can be gotten from the Windows ADK or AIK if Windows 7.

Comment: @AntoineL I'm reading them, but from your comment it appears I'm misunderstanding them _(I apologize for that)_? There isn't a "hot debate" - when I first posted the question and answer in 2020, a few folks took issue with the "image" nomenclature, which is why I added the two annotation sections to the top of the question and answer _(there can't be a debate about facts, as facts are facts and, except for the portions in italics which are my opinions, everything in this answer are facts pulled directly from Microsoft Docs [Windows Man Pages])_.

Comment: WinPE version 1 (in OPK, 2001-2005, suitable for Win XP & 2003) did not include any "_imaging_" utility, so no `ImageX`; it came later with Longhorn (2005) and WinPE 2 (Vista era) albeit it works very well with XP. You can also use `Dism` from e.g. WinPE 10.x to image anything NTFS-based, probably as early as NT 3.x. What does not (usually) work is to use a lower version of WinPE than the corresponding OS. So the last WinPE (or WinRE) installed on a USB drive will perform anywhere.

Comment: If you get an Access Denied error when trying to apply-image, you can perform a quick format of the partition you're applying to. You're going to wipe the data with the /apply-image and it's just causing NTFS permission errors.

Comment: When fixing the EFI partition, you have it mounted on Y. The BCDBoot command needs to copy to Y: also. As written it'll copy to the main c drive.
BcdBoot C:\Windows /s Y: /f UEFI vs BcdBoot C:\Windows /s C: /f UEFI

Comment: cannot find bootrec in Win11 anymore

Comment: **WARNING** Do not use this method for moving windows partition into other drive! It does not perform it correctly. I've tried it multiple times in virtual machine, it always had errors https://superuser.com/q/1775992/1133411

Comment: @megapro17 Nothing in this answer is factually inaccurate, with all info collated directly from Microsoft Docs with man page links all thoughout. Were you able to replicate this on a clean install per zoomzoom's comment in the question you linked to? If so, did you file a bug report with Microsoft? I've never encountered the issue you're running into on StackExchange or SpiceWorks - there are Microsoft [vendor] employees who monitor SpiceWorks daily and interact with users, so if you are able to replicate this on a clean install, I would also recommend posting the same on there. _Cont'd..._

Comment: @megapro17 _Cont'd..._ What you're experiencing is very odd behavior and would imply there's something wonky configured with the OS being imaged _(I have no idea what though, only that what you're experiencing is very abnormal since `DISM` is literally the backbone of Windows, which makes this even more odd since wonky things tend to not occur with `DISM` due to how critical it is)_. If unable to replicate on a clean install, it's something with the OS being imaged; if able to replicate, install the ADK and use the `DISM` version that comes with that to rule out the version within WinPE's WIM

Answer (score 14):

**What is the most efficient, native way to image a Windows partition?**

There isn't one any more since Windows Backup is being phased out
(probably because this was a bad product to start with).

Only DISM is left, but it only does file backup, not partition image backup.
Its new
[Full Flash Update (FFU) images](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/deploy-windows-using-full-flash-update--ffu)
takes a sector-by-sector image of the entire disk, which unfortunately also
includes unused sectors, so not at all efficient.

**Why is the native method generally the best method for most users?**

It isn't for Windows, as above. Microsoft has left the field in favor of third-party
products.

**How does the native method differ from conventional cloning?**

DISM does not do cloning at all.

**What are the pros and cons of native versus third-party tools?**

The pros of third-party tools is that they work well and efficiently.
Most are also free to use.

Example products are AOMEI Backupper, Clonezilla, Macrium Reflect,
EaseUS ToDo BackUp.
YMMV.

**Historical note**: DISM was conceived by Microsoft decades ago in an
ancient version of Windows (Vista), using the
[Windows Imaging Format (WIM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Imaging_Format),
which is a file-based disk image format, used mostly for
software distribution.
For backup, Microsoft has created Windows Backup, of which a limited
version is still available in Windows 10 as
"Back up and Restore (Windows 7)", but without its problematic image
backup feature. The use of DISM as a backup utility is very strongly
*not* recommended.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112551/discussion-on-answer-by-harrymc-what-is-the-most-efficient-native-way-to-image).

Comment: This answer would have been useful if it actually explained the pitfalls of using `DISM` for partition imaging/cloning purposes, instead of just opinionating against its use. I have one reason for not relying on `DISM` for partition cloning: it can't handle not-downloaded OneDrive file pointers. Otherwise, it always did it's job for an off-the-shelf tool.