# Is there a built in function to create image of the system?

Tags: backup, images, updates

I have here a lot of computers all the same hardware. They came with not up to date Windows 10 installed on them. I need to update them to the latest and install chrome that's pretty much it. Updating takes ages so I'd create an image of one up to date PC and use it. Is there a built in windows function, or is there a script that does the trick? I know easeus but can't use 3rd party. Thanks

Comment: Do some reading here>>>>>>>https://superuser.com/questions/1581803/what-is-the-most-efficient-native-way-to-image-a-windows-partition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go ahead with Sysprep. It's a tool used for generalizing a Windows image (and it's Windows integrated). Then you can use WDS (Windows Deployment Services) on a Windows Server computer to deploy the image on your computers through PXE, using an autounattend.xml file (you can also use SCCM).

Here's some links you can read about Sysprep and :

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/sysprep--generalize--a-windows-installation

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wds/windows-deployment-services-portal

https://argonsys.com/microsoft-cloud/library/part-3-how-to-configure-wds-unattend-xml-file-windows-pe-image-and-nano-server-image-to-deploy-a-nano-server-at-a-scale/