# Windows 10 Partition restore issue with Macrium Reflect

Tags: bootloader, partition-recovery, macrium

I tried to reset my Windows 10 to an older Version and this failed.
Luckily I had created an image before with Macrium Reflect and this
image is in 2 files on other partitions.
I booted the Laptop from Partition 3 and tried to restore the
Image with Macrium to partition 1 -
but MR keeps telling me that I would need Windows PE and
it was unable to make a Windows PE boot entry!!!
All I want ist my bytes and sectors back to Partition 1 -
I do not want a new PE Partition and I care for the
bootability of my system for myself with EasyBCD.
I simply want those sectors back.
Maybe I should have used an Easus Product rather than
a Macrium Product - but this is too late now.
Please tell me if there is a way to restore the
reflect image without booting in Windows PE.
thanks

Comment: You could reinstall windows then copy files off the image.  I had a similar issue when trying to restore individual partitions when the system was Windows(I think I used clonezilla or dd, or maybe macrium). The problem was maybe that Windows has the 100MB partition .. for me windows wasn't finding the thing. It wasn't a fault with Macrium.. But it was suggested to me that I should've used DISM(native windows program) to do it.  Or, no doubt, if you use Macrium to make an image of the entire hard drive. Then that writes for windows fine.

Comment: Easeus and Macrium are great.  But for copying individual partitions somewhere and having it bootable, maybe you should use windows native tools

Comment: As @barlop mentioned, Windows has [natively](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800) supported partition imaging since Windows XP, of which does not result in configuration issues like you're currently experiencing since WIMs [**W**indows **IM**ages] are restorable from WinPE/WinRE. WinPE is **Win**dows **P**reinstallation **E**nvironment _(such as Windows install media)_ and can be created using the Windows ADK, however you already have a WinPE partition: WinRE [**Win**dows **R**ecovery **E**nvironment] _(WinRE is WinPE with two to three recovery specific WinPE Optional Components)_.

Answer (score -1):

thanks all!
I found out the problem was the I wanted to restore
to the system partition that contains the boot loader.
In this case macrium forces you to use a Windows PE boot.
thanks!