# Option to choose to reinstall image on reboot on a windows laptop

Tags: windows, reboot, disk-image, reinstall

I want to do a fresh install of my laptops which I use for my work. I want to make a good image from the fresh install and when the computers starts I want two bootup options:

> 1. Start Windows
> 2. Reinstall image

and the PC should start automatically with the current windows version after x seconds. In the past I know that Norton Ghost did something like this but that is not available anymore. What alternatives are there to do this?

Comment: Sounds to me like the Windows feature "Bootable Recovery Partition". Usually this feature is used by big PC manufacturer to provide a simple way to reinstall Windows. However the used image for "reinstallation" can also be generated from an existing Windows installation.

Comment: You would create the base image using `Dism` _(see this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800))_, then modify the [BCD store](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/adding-boot-entries) to add the boot options. By default, Windows will show the boot option selection menu for 30s, after which it boots the default option _(usually the first)_. You can also customize the [WinRE boot menu](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/add-a-custom-tool-to-the-windows-re-boot-options-menu) to add it there as well

Comment: Windows supports this out of the box.  You can Reset your Windows installation from within Windows at anytime.