# how to remove win 7 boot loader after upgrading to win 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, boot, bootloader

I did an on line upgrade of win 7 laptop to win 10. Everything works as it should but I find I have both the boot loader for win 7 and win 10 on the HDD,. How do I remove the boot loader for win 7 it seems to slow down the computer but that may be caused by something else.

Comment: The bootloader entry can be removed from the BCD store via `BCDedit` and the boot files themselves from the Win7 boot partition, which is likely at `C:\Boot` _(Windows 10 should have three partitions: WinRE, Boot, and OS)_. If the Win7 and Win10 boot files are both on the Boot partition, they're likely not able to be distinguished from each other; in this case, boot to WinRE, format the Boot partition, then rebuild the boot files via step #5 under _How do I configure system partitions on a new drive for applying an image?_ at the bottom of [this](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800) answer

Comment: Wow that is quite complex. Thanks for the answer. I have to think about if I want to do that to a working machine.

Comment: @JW0914 As I look into how to do this I see it requires a windows media. I do not have this as it was an in place over the internet upgrade what do I do?

Comment: All you need to do is boot to WinRE [**Win**dows **RE**covery] - the commands only take a few min to run. General FYI, it's recommended to do a clean of Windows 10 when you have time, as some OEM drivers from Windows 7 and 8/8.1 are not compatible with Windows 10 and will result in BSODs _(there is no way to efficiently uninstall OEM drivers since they're copied into subdirectories of `%WinDir%` and often renamed `oem<#>.inf`; capture a [WIM](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800) of the `C:` partition prior to doing so - that way you have a backup of your current setup)_

Comment: As already stated I can not do a fresh install ow win 10 I do not have the media it was an in place over the internet upgrade.

Comment: You can download the Windows install ISO from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) and use [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) to create a bootable USB. _(to ensure we're on the same page, fix what you asked: WinRE [Settings - Update & Security - Recovery -Advanced Startup - Troubleshoot - Advanced - Command Prompt] whereas to clean install Windows 10, you'd use the aofrementioned Microsoft and Rufus links)_