# Not enough space in System Reserved partition (for shadow copy) when trying to create System Image

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, setup, system-reserved-partition, windows-system-image

I do know that system image is a legacy way to create Windows 10 backups, and I only use it as added helper method.

I freshly installed my Windows 10 19041 Workstation and in the setup I created a 300G partition on a 1T unpartitioned SATA SDD. Windows 10 setup created an additional 50M(!) System Reserved partition automatically, the size was its chosen size. I did know this habit of Windows setup, thought all OK so far.

Now I am trying to create a System Image, and got the error message. The message has right, below 500M the minimum req for shadow copy is 50M, so in my 50M partition, where 31M is reserved obviously there are no free 50M space. (then why it picked the 50M size during setup?) In my prev Windows 10 install the size of System Partition was 131M... also automatically created...)

**Question**

If I would like to have the System Image creation possibility, what are my options?

a) Can I somehow resize this System Reserved partitions (I suppose only with 3rd party tool, because the Windows System Partition has to be moved) If there is a trusted tool, (I means security, not data safety) I would give it a shoot)

b) In case it is not recommended, I am willing to reinstall my Windows 10, but it is possible to somehow let Windows 10 during the setup create bigger System Reserved partition supposing there are 300G unpartitioned space?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The MSR partition does not get backed up, as it's a placeholder partition _(it doesn't technically even need to exist and most OEMs ship PCs without that partition for some reason)_. General FYI, Windows Backup is inefficient, with the recommended native way to create backups being to [capture a WIM](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800) _(I explain why it's inefficient under the first quoted statement in [this](https://superuser.com/a/1582279/529800) answer)_

Comment: Thx for your comments. Regardless it is backed up or not, as you see the checkbox before it is mandatory, and grayed checked, which is prevents to create the System Image. Which is the preferred way to resize it, or if that is not recommended is there a way to create a bigger one when running again the Windows Setup, or based on your suggestion that is unnecessary, is there a way to setup Win 10 _without_ it. Or should I delete it? (how?)

Comment: If your motherboard is: **UEFI:** no, the MSR partition should not be a different size; **BIOS:** it can be resized to 128MB [RAW; formatted would be 100MB]. Regardless, creating a system image via Windows Backup is not recommended _(Windows Backup was depreciated by Microsoft because it's inferior to WIMs/ESDs)_ and I encourage reading why in the first part of [this](https://superuser.com/a/1582279/529800) answer. Folks create backups to ensure data parity remains [data is verified as not being corrupted] and Windows backup does not offer parity, nor is even remotely storage efficient.

Comment: Many thx. Meanwhile I reading this DISM thing. My primary goal is to have create a very robust snapshot of the Windows system partition, so in case a disk crash or change I can restore it by booting a Windows  Repair disk, and do something there and restore the saved snapshot, and got my Windows fully configured back. Other methods like installing a new Windows, then restoring my files back are not good for me, because, even many things are automated, still 2 days work for me to configure a newly installed Win. So it is not clear yet for me, if this DISM thing is suitable for me

Comment: @g.pickardou - If you want a robust snapshot of a windows system partition then you don't want to use Windows Backup to do it.

Comment: @Ramhound Thx, OK, I am evolving my concept (at least it is in progress :-)

Comment: @g.pickardou That's exactly what capturing and applying a WIM does - all you'd need to do is follow Steps 1 and/or 2 under [Imaging](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800) _(it's copy and paste, no knowledge of how it works required)_ while booted to WinRE [Windows Recovery]. If you need help with the process, please leave a comment under that answer and we'll get you squared away.

Comment: Many thx again. I upgrade my 10 years old emergency snapshot/restore method to DISM. In case you write a 1-3 line answer (practically your first comment() I am going to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Concluded to use the completely free Macrium Reflect 7 (free edition)
Fully functional, even can do incremental images, created WinRE Restore disk, which boots with the very similar GUI. Works like charm.

When restoring it if flexible regarding the partition sizes, can shrink btw. (of course if there was free space on the source partition).