# reboot and select proper boot device error after boot from new SSD

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, ssd

I just got my new Crucial P5 CT2000P5SSD8 2 TB which should replace another SSD as the boot drive. After successfully cloning the whole contend from the old SSD with Macrium Reflect, I am not able to boot from the new SSD. For some reasons I get the 'reboot and select proper boot device' Error Message in the boot menu after trying to boot from this device. I changed the boot priority but for some reason it is not working.

Here are my specs:

```
Case:           Sharkoon TG4 PC case RGB
Mainboard:      Gigabyte B450M-S2H
Processor:      AMD Ryzen 5 3600 6Cores 12Threads 4.2GHz Boost
RAM:            Corsair Vengeance RGB PRO 3200MHz
Power supply:   BeQuiet 650W
GPU:            GTX 2070S KFA2
SSD 2.5":       120GB Sandisk + 500GB Crucial
SSD m.2 PCIe:   2TB Crucial P5 CT2000P5SSD8
HDD 2.5":       320GB Western Digital
```

Comment: If you cannot boot from the new SSD, the cloning was done incorrectly. Use another cloning product.

Comment: The BCD store is missing/corrupted - boot to WinRE/WinPE and execute the following: **UEFI:** `BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /RebuildBCD` _(if it doesn't resolve, perform Step 5 in the last section of this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800), mounting the EFI partition at `Y:` via `DiskPart`)_ || **BIOS:** `BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /FixBoot && BootRec /RebuildBCD`. If this doesn't resolve the issue, use the linked to answer to natively clone your partitions.

Comment: Thank you guys very much for the help! I already figured out how to boot from the SSD. I throwed the cloned Data away and flashed the OS from an USB Stick. Windows is doing a good job there