# Converting MBR to GPT in a computer using UEFI firmware

Tags: windows, boot, partitioning, mbr, gpt

I recently bought a refurbished Dell Precision 7510 running Windows 10 and decided to clone the included HHD to an NVMe SSD. In the process, I noticed my laptop's partition system was set to MBR and my laptop has been in UEFI mode all the time I have been using it. I have read in many articles a GPT partition system should always be used with EFI boot and am unsure if my refurbisher did this for a reason.

Should I convert the partition system and, if so, how should I do so in a safe way?

Comment: Research MBR2GPT

Comment: If your system is currently working then do not try to break it. Trying to convert it means knowing exactly what other things you need to change at the same time.

Comment: UEFI and BIOS are not the same things:  [BIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS) [**B**asic **I**nput / **O**utput **S**ystem], developed in '75, is a 16bit firmware with massive limitations; [UEFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) [**U**nified **E**xtensible **F**irmware **I**nterface], developed in '05, is a 64bit firmware w/ a multitude of features BIOS is incapable of supporting _(CSM mode emulates BIOS' 16bit architecture within a 32bit environment, only existing to support distros incapable of EFI boot pre-2016ish)_

Comment: Converting to GPT is always recommended with UEFI firmware, else boot performance is severely degraded; AFAIK, it's not possible to [install](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-setup-installing-using-the-mbr-or-gpt-partition-style) Windows to an MBR partition table w/ CSM mode disabled, as EFI boot requires GPT partition ID `c12a7328-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93b` _(I don't believe `DiskPart` supports the `EFh` MBR [partition type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_type#List_of_partition_IDs))_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Windows works, then everything is already configured properly. If your disk is indeed partitioned using MBR, then the UEFI is configured to emulate a BIOS and Windows boots as if it was a BIOS. We know that because Windows supports MBR only when booting in BIOS mode and GPT only when booting in UEFI mode. It's not broken, don't fix it.

If you want to convert to GPT for some reason, the `mbr2gpt` tool can do that if your system satisfies a few requirements. But if you don't have any actual problem that you're trying to solve, I'd advise to keep it as it is.

Comment: Converting to GPT is always recommended w/ UEFI, else boot performance is severely degraded; AFAIK, it's not possible to [install](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-setup-installing-using-the-mbr-or-gpt-partition-style) Windows to an MBR partition w/ CSM mode disabled, as EFI boot requires GPT partition ID `c12a7328-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93b` _(I don't believe `DiskPart` supports MBR [partition type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_type#List_of_partition_IDs) `EFh`)_. CSM mode only exists to support distros incapable of EFI boot pre-2016ish

Comment: @JW0914 You're right, but since OP isn't complaining about boot times I'd rather advise them to stick to MBR+CSM rather than risk breaking something for no good reason.

Comment: I understand that perspective and while I've never used `mbr2gpt`, simply capturing a [WIM](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800) of the OS partition prior to using it would negate all potential risks

Comment: So in short I should research `mbr2gpt` and creare a WIM of my OS to make a successful translation to GPT

Comment: @james _If you need GPT_. There's nothing wrong with MBR. GPT has its advantages, but MBR is already there and it's working, that's a big plus. If you want to convert anyway, I'd personally go with some disk cloning software rather than WIMs. A competent cloning/imaging tool will let you restore the whole disk without any extra tinkering. With WIMs you can only capture partition contents, but not their layout and boot config.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

UEFI firmware can install Windows 10 to MBR, but the UEFI BIOS must be set to
Legacy Mode. Without Legacy Mode, only GPT is allowed for Windows 64-bit.

[MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) is just as good as
[GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table).
The only advantage of GPT is that it allows using hard disks of more than 2 TB.

Note that Windows can use a GPT disk in Legacy Mode, as long as this is not the
system drive. An additional disk can be in GPT format.

Converting between MBR and GPT via Windows will destroy the disk's contents.
Third-party utilities exist that can do the conversion without data-loss,
but it's still advised to make a disk-image backup in case it fails.

Comment: UEFI and BIOS are not the same things _(context matters in this case)_

Comment: @JW0914: There is still some confusion in terms. Many people say BIOS when they mean the UEFI firmware, and even some UEFI firmwares do this error. It's a problem when writing an answer that the poster will comprehend.

Comment: OEMs conflate the two to consumers and we should be better than that: [BIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS) [**B**asic **I**nput / **O**utput **S**ystem], developed in '75, is a 16bit firmware with massive limitations; [UEFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) [**U**nified **E**xtensible **F**irmware **I**nterface], developed in '05, is a 64bit firmware w/ a multitude of features BIOS is incapable of supporting _(CSM mode emulates BIOS' 16bit architecture within a 32bit environment, only existing to support distros incapable of EFI boot pre-2016ish)_