# Changed UEFI from Legacy to UEFI Boot and now I can't boot Windows

Tags: boot, bios, uefi, cmos, legacy

I've changed UEFI from Legacy to UEFI Boot using MBR2GPT, setting the boot option to the hard drive, but after `mbr2gpt` finished, I received an error about an XML file, which I ignored. 
Upon rebooting, I receive error:

```
PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable

PXE-MOF: Exiting PXE-ROM

No bootable device found. Press any key to reboot the machine
```

Will resetting the CMOS battery fix this?

Comment: `mbr2gpt` doesn't reconfigure your BIOS, it just prepares Windows to boot in EFI mode rather than legacy. You have to manually make sure that EFI boot is enabled. Did you do that?

Comment: “Will reseting the cmos battery fix that?” - it probably will not, you need to disable legacy mode, and make sure you have configured your system for UEFI mode.  Hopefully, you have a backup of your drive.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't really mind about the data on the disk. Is there any case that if I put a USB with windows installer in it I can maybe reinstall or repair windows or will I get the same error?

Comment: Windows is not easily repaired outside of Windows, let alone, attempting to repair an external installation of Windows

Comment: @Ramhound That's the entire purpose of WinRE

Comment: @lidistat67 Provided `mbr2gpt` assigned the correct GUIDs to the EFI, WinRE, and OS partitions, boot from the Install USB, open a terminal via `Shift`+`F10` and follow Step 5 in the last section of [this](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800) answer, where `C:` is the OS partition, which will likely not be `C:` in WinPE/WinRE - list via `Diskpart` → `lis vol` _(you'll mount the EFI partition via `DiskPart`: to verify the correct GUIDs are set, select the applicable partition (`lis par` → `sel par #`) → `det par` and match the GUID listed to those listed via `help cre par pri`)_

Comment: @JW0914 - In all my years of attempting to resolve a crash, that left me with only WinRE, I have never successfully repaired Windows when Windows was unable to do it myself.

Comment: @Ramhound `BootRec` and `BcdBoot` fix all boot issues, `DISM` and `SFC` fix all Windows system file issues _(if without internet access, an `install.wim`/`install.esd` from a Windows install ISO is required for `DISM`)_, with the two things that can't be fixed without a backup being the user and system Registry hives _(located within `%UserProfile%` & `%WinDir%\System32\config` - a Task to back up registry hives daily/weekly is a good idea, as they're only ~250MB)_ and drivers _(as of v1809, drivers are backed up to the Component Store (`%WinDir%\WinSxS`) every time a bi-annual update occurs)_