# Windows 10 could not read disk, could not format as well

Tags: boot, partitioning, ssd, external-hard-drive

I newly bought an NVME 1TB M2 SSD and would like to replace this with my laptop's 128GB M2 SSD (Main HDD for boot).

After cloning the disk with MiniTool Partition Wizard, it seems that the disk is damaged or corrupted?

**I used an external NVME SSD Adaptor Casing to connect my fresh NVME SSD to my laptop via a USB C to USB cable into my laptop USB port**
The drive did not show up at first of course, but then when I opened up Disk Management window it Shows there as "Disk 2" Unallocated partiion with no drive letter yet.

**So I continued these steps**

1. Opened up MiniTool Partition Wizard and it was able to detect the SSD and I proceed to do a disk clone of my original Boot HDD to this fresh NVME SSD because I want to replace the new 1TB NVME SSD with my original 128GB Boot HDD. Need more space..
2. After cloning, I shut down my laptop and swap the boot HDD.
3. After turning on, my laptop wont boot, wont even open BIOS.
4. I swapped back the old HDD and then plugged in the new SSD via USB.
5. Window then shows D;\ is not accessible, Incorrect Function as shown
   [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pprj4.png)

This is my original 128GB SSD that came with the laptop
[Original ADATA 128GB SSD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/al3PK.jpg)
This is my new 1TB NVME SSD
[NEW Verbatim Vi3000 NVME SSD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/js1bV.jpg)

**What I've tried.**

1. Right click on the disk and select format, but the format window doesn't pop up
2. Went into Disk Management, its shown as Disk 2, but there's no volume or partition shown.
   [Disk Management Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbDeB.png)
3. Open up MiniToll Partition Wizard again, and this time it doesn't detect the disk at all.
   [MiniTool Partition Wizard, No Disk 3 shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1G4TC.png)
4. Tried using DiskPart in CMD as administrator, "list disk" does not show the disk (Disk 2), but then it can be selected. So I went on to try "clear" command but it says DiskPart has encountered an error: Incorrect function.
   [Diskpart, Clean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeMZk.png)
5. Then I tried "detail disk" to view details, at the "status" it says "unusable". How do i fix this?
   [status unusable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVLKk.png)
6. then i tried selecting the volume and use "format" but then it gives me the same error message DiskPart has encountered an error: Incorrect function.
   [unable to format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suV5h.png)
7. Tried uninstall the driver, restarted my laptop, and plugged the drive back in and it's still the same issue.

Does this mean my new SSD is gone??

**Now, assuming my laptop could not support the new NVME SSD, it's okay.
Since I have the NVME external casing, I can use it as an external HDD.**
But now it seems that the HDD is not usable anymore after the disk clone.
I would like to bring it back to life and use it as an external HDD since it's still new! :(

Tried all the methods I could find on Google but none of it worked...

Comment: Are you sure your laptop supports NVME? If it had a SATA M.2 originally it's unlikely it support NVME.

Comment: But in that case it shouldn't even show up as a device in the OS...

Comment: @user1686 True, but we don't know either way because the computer didn't boot with it installed, hence my suspicion.

Comment: Assuming my laptop doesn't support NVME, I could use it as an external HDD, but now since it is corrupted/damaged/cannot detect after the disk clone, am trying to find a way to bring it back to life so I can use it as an external. Just bought this last week! :(

Comment: Maybe you should have it returned while you can...but yeah can't say for sure about your data security

Comment: There's something going on with the NVME casing - try unseating and reseating the NVME SSD within its case, as short of static discharge damaging a PCB component on the NVME SSD, it's unlikely the NVME has hardware damage _(the case or USB connection is more likely the issue)_. For cloning a Windows OS partition, the easiest and most efficient method is Windows' [native](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800) method using `Dism`

Comment: Btw, there could be chance that it's the enclosure happened to be fried/broken, and the new drive is merely unbootable because the utility didn't do it right / the UEFI is bugged / etc. Maybe you should try put it back to the internal slot and see how things are with some USB live medium.