# Would a small Raid 1 setup suit the need of a home user?

Tags: raid, raid-1

First of all I have read a few discussions about how raid is not a backup option, but let's say I ONLY want to try to protect my Datas from hardware failure.

Currently, in my gaming pc, I have a 1 TB SSD, and a 2 TB SSD, used for most stuff, and beside that, still in the PC there is a 6TB HDD, and I also use a fairly old 2 TB external drive.
In my 6TB HDD I have a lot of different things, ranging from some backup of some files, to family photos, to vacations films, "normal" films and series, anime, games saves, some work files ...
And the most "important" stuff is copied from that HDD to the external drive, every couple weeks, when more important stuff gets added.

I'm considering changing that 6 TB HDD, to 2 a bit bigger HDDs, and place them in Raid 1, and to still keep the important stuff copied on an external drive in another house.
The goal is to try to secure a bit these datas against hardware failure, I don't care about unintentional deletion, ransonwares, viruses and all ..

Personnaly I find it nice to not have to manually copy everything every time besides the important stuff on the external drive, and I would like to keep this operating on my own gaming pc (disregarding availability, which I know is the point of raid), would that be a decent/good option, or would it be just simpler and better to just get 2 new HDDs and manually copy stuff on both of them? Would raid 1 operate on lets say 2x 10 TB drives, is it too big?

Thank you for taking time to read this

Best regards,
XorKoS

Comment: You can use Windows' [native method](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800) of backing up partitions/directories [`Dism /Capture-Image`] to create a highly compressed image [`.wim`] with parity [data verification] that is immune from corruption provided `/CheckIntegrity /Verify` are always used. New images can be appended to the base image [`Dism /Append-Image`] and the backup can be configured to be completely automated via [Task Scheduler](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/about-the-task-scheduler).

Comment: *"I don't care about unintentional deletion, ransomwares, viruses and all[.]*" - I might rethink this. Personally, I was hit by some fluke ransomware a couple years ago on a completely personal PC that otherwise had no known security issues. About 250GB was encrypted in a few hours and it was only by luck that I noticed what was happening. I have had more hard drives fail than any other type of data disaster, but honestly, ransomware has gotten *extremely* popular recently and isn't a joke when it happens (though having backups not attached to the PC can definitely help save your data) .

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's amazing that you're considering all of this before a disaster strikes.

The major problem in your setup is lack of automated backups. Manually copying everything is not a long-term solution. As you've already discovered it feels like a chore. It's also prone to mistakes and you either have to keep only the most recent copy of all files, which doesn't give you proper protection against accidental modification or deletion, or to make full copies of everything, which is more time- and space-consuming.

Consider automating your backup. I'm using [Veeam Agent](https://www.veeam.com/windows-endpoint-server-backup-free.html) to back up my Windows PC. You can set it to start automatically when you plug in a particular USB drive. It uses a proprietary storage format, which is a disadvantage, but this format lets it make incremental backups: only files that have changed are added to the backup repository and thus multiple versions of files are stored without duplicating unchanged files. Once in a while you can repeat a full backup, so that you can delete versions before it without breaking the repository (individual increments can't be deleted because following increments may rely on data inside them). Veeam Agent can also restore your system drive into a working state when it's too broken to boot. You just have to prepare a recovery USB beforehand. It's not a perfect solution, but it's good enough and the basic feature set is free.

Another alternative is [Duplicati](https://www.duplicati.com/), which also uses a proprietary incremental backup repository, but lets you delete single increments. I didn't have much luck with it though - all backups were corrupted immediately after creation. The moral is that you should check if your backup is restorable before you need it.

We'll get back to backups in a while, but now let's talk about RAID. RAID offers you essentially only availability in case of hard disk failure. You seem to understand that it doesn't offer any protection against malware, mistakes and software errors. It also doesn't protect your drives from being fried by a faulty power supply or flooded in an unfortunate accident. The only benefit of RAID is that when a single drive dies, your files are still available and after replacing the drive loading data back on it is (maybe) a bit less of a hassle than restoring backups. Whether this matters for you or not is up to you. Anyway, you'd still need backups.

My last point is that NAS-es exist. They are self-contained little servers that you load up with drive(s) and they just do their job, sometimes offering some extra features. They are like USB drives, except they are connected to the network and designed to be always on. If you don't mind paying for the power to keep the drives spinning, they can be a great solution for main storage or for backups. For example higher-end Synology models like the [DS220+](https://www.synology.com/en-us/products/DS220+) offer an integrated backup solution similar to Veeam's, but hosted and orchestrated from the NAS. These backups are also incremental, single increments can be deleted anytime, and you have an option to restore an unbootable system. Not to mention a ton of extra features (Dropbox-like file and photo sync, virtual machines, Docker...) and possibility to run RAID in these. (I promise I'm not selling this stuff, I just love them.) I don't think other NAS manufacturers offer any dedicated backup solutions, but you could use them for Veeam or any other backup solution over the network. QNAP has good reputation as a NAS manufacturer too.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. I'm still unsure if a NAS is something i'd need or not, i know these things exist since years, but i have trouble justifying having one, over just adding a few drives to my home PC ? Maybe it has less chances to fry from a random problem, but my pc is not alws turned on. Also the 2nd point where i'm unsure since years is do i need real "backup", personnaly most of the data i want to store and "not lose" would be mostly multimedia, not like i'd like to restore an old version on any of those things, and well i don't think i'd care about a full windows backup. Idk

Comment: If that's the case, then you may be good with just an automated file copier like [Bvckup2](https://bvckup2.com/). Take a look at the [DataHoarder subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/DataHoarder/) too. They do something similar, but with dozens of TBs. You can learn a few tricks from them.

Comment: Oh, that looks interesting, and it's maybe easier to setup and use, and also easier to transition to. Haven't seen that sub in years, but now that you mention it i remember, i will check it for sure to see what people think there, thank you.