# How can I install Windows 10 on a SSD, but boot to it from ESD on another HDD disk

Tags: windows-10, boot, uefi, nvme

I have a PC with an HDD and an NVMe SSD on a PCIe adapter card, both formatted as GPT disks. PC is HP Compaq Elite 8300. Its (old) UEFI BIOS does not recognize that SDD so I cannot just install Windows 10 on it and boot.

While browsing for the solution I saw suggestions saying that it is possible to boot from HDD to the operating system on SSD, but found no suggestions on how to do it.

So I tried to first install Windows 10 on the HDD and then added second Windows install to SSD thinking that I'd be able to boot to it from the ESD partition on HDD. If that succeeded, I would remove the Windows on HDD from the boot menu and erase Windows from it. Unfortunately, when the second installation came to the first reboot of the installation procedure, it booted to a blue screen complaining about missing C:\Windows\System32\winload.efi

I'd be grateful to hear any suggestions and/or for the links to helpful information.

Comment: Do you mean *ESP* (EFI system partition)? Besides, are you hiding the fact/context that your SSD is not accessible by your UEFI firmware?

Comment: Does the UEFI firmware not offer the ability to install drivers so it does recognize the NVMe drive? You can try housing the EFI partition on the HDD with the BCD Store pointing to the OS partition on the SSD _(see #3 in [this](https://superuser.com/a/1657524/529800) answer - the EFI partition on the SSD should be removed if that's done)_. If that does not work, it's likely not going to be possible without UEFI having the drivers to recognize the NVMe drive or the PCIe card providing a mechanism so older UEFI versions do recognize the NVMe drive.

Comment: Try installing the grub bootloader