# Windows10 not booting

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

I have used my laptop for more than 4 years now. It came with the original Windows 10 Home Single Language. Recently there was a new update on Windows 10. I updated it. Since then, Windows 10 doesn't boot. I am sure that the problem is with Windows 10 because I have Phoenix OS and it boot and works perfectly.
I use a Dell Inspiron 3542. The problem is that, it won't go passed the Dell loading screen. I have attached an image below.
1st I get to chose what OS I need to boot to. Then when I select Windows10, it keeps on loading for eternity. [keeps loading like this, forever](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TuAl.jpg)

Comment: Hard reboot it 2x in a row _(hold down the power button until it shuts off [~7s] as soon as the spinning Windows icon loads)_ and it will load WinRE if the update wasn't a b-annual update [v20H2, v20H1, etc.] _(if the latter is the case, it's likely you'll need to leave it until the OS install is finalized - bi-annual updates are essentially a Repair Install)_. WinRE will first try Automatic Repair, but if that doesn't work, boot back to WinRE → Advanced → Troubleshooting → Command Prompt → `BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /FixBoot && BootRec /RebuildBCD` _(remove 2nd command if UEFI)_ → Reboot

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to [download the Windows 10 ISO from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO) with the Media Creation Tool and to reinstall Window 10 from a USB made using that tool, keeping your current files.

**Before reinstalling, make a disk image in case there is data loss.** If you can do so from Phoenix, good; if not, boot from a USB with disk imaging tools such as [Linux dd](https://linuxhandbook.com/dd-command/) or a [Macrium Reflect Free](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) boot device.

If you cannot reinstall from Window 10 ISO on USB, likely you've made some change in the BIOS/UEFI settings to install Phoenix OS, and will need to [revert the settings to the original values](https://accatech.com/reset-dell-bios-settings-inspiron-latitude-laptop/) for Windows. You may lose Phoenix OS, in that case, and will have [to reinstall it](https://www.xpertstec.com/how-to-install-phoenix-os-in-dual-boot-mode-with-windows-10/), or give it up.

Comment: This is not a solution to a simple boot issue that can be repaired via WinRE/WinPE using WinRE's Automatic Repair or `BootRec`, `BcdEdit`, or `Sfc`. If the BCD Store isn't the issue, it's likely processing a bi-annual update and is still performing one of the seven configuration passes _(OP would need to state what update they applied to determine)_. Windows also [natively](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800) supports capturing, and applying,  an image from WinRE/WinPE via `Dism` that's more efficient and doesn't rely upon third-party boot media or Linux.

Comment: @JW0914, it is easier to download Macrium Reflect or similar tool and let it *build* Windows RE (Win PE) and *install* it to a USB.

Comment: How is that easier when all Windows installs come with WinPE installed [WinRE]? It can be accessed in three ways: interrupt the Windows bootloader twice in a row and WinRE auto-loads _(same applies if a boot issue prevents Windows from loading twice in a row)_, hold `Shift` while selecting _Restart_ from the power menu drop down on the login screen, or from _Settings_ while booted to the OS.