# Migrate from SATA (over M2) ssd to nvme (over M2) ssd with clonezilla

Tags: windows-10, ssd, clonezilla, nvme

I have a laptop with two drives: one is magnetic (1TB) used for data (and some windows folders) , the other is a little ssd (128GB) used for OSes (win10 and xubuntu).

Now what I'm trying to do is migrating the OS (SSD) drive to a newer nvme drive, my issue is that doing a drive clone with clonezilla (and altering the archive file names from sdb# to nvme0n1p# and the content of following files: `disk` `parts` `dev-fs.list` `blkid.list` and `blkdev.list` I got errors when windows starts (windows starts but gives error). I also tried (from windows recovery tool, on the efi partition on `K:`, with `C:` as windows volume) the command bcdboot `c:\windows /l it-IT /s k: /f ALL` but I'm still not able to start windows.

Obviously putting in the old drive it runs

EDIT:
Further try:
I did a backup with windows image backup utility, restored it and same issue

Comment: Why do you need to rename files in order to clone a disk? And why are you cloning a Windows disk with a Linux utility such as clonezilla?

Comment: because otherweise clonezilla does not find a matching disk and does not restore at all.

Comment: So use another utility that doesn't have such problems. Example: [AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.ubackup.com/free-backup-software.html).

Comment: Currently it's not viable because the old drive is at the office (I got the pc with new drive in and external drive with the images). I'm also on vacation so the old drive is really out-of-reach

Comment: @DDS In Windows, cloning a drive at the disk-level/partition-level is inefficient, as NTFS has been the default filesystem since XP _(users don't need partition-level/disk-level images containing offset, alignment, block size, etc. and doing so often results in inconvenient configuration issues)_. To resolve boot issues, boot to WinPE/WinRE and try [Step 5](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800) [_How do I configure system partitions on a new drive for applying an image?_], else use that section to create the proper partitions, then use `Dism` to clone partition data [_Imaging section_].

Comment: _Cont'd..._ @DDS Windows Image Backup _(rebranded from Windows Backup and Restore)_ is inefficient and prone to corruption since it uses VHDs, versus the WIM/ESD format via `Dism` _(I go into detail within the first section of [this](https://superuser.com/a/1582279/529800) answer)_