# Windows update issue: can't find Program Files and my user folder from linux bootable cd

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, hard-drive

during an update windows doesn't start anymore: it keeps trying "recovery actions" but it is stuck in a loop.

For this reason I created a kubuntu bootable disk and started it on my laptop, to at least recover my files. For some reason I can see each folder except:

- Program files: it is empty (while "Program Files x86" is ok)
- My personal folder: I can only see "Public", "Default User", "user.migrated"

Maybe windows deleted them during the update/recovery? Or it has to do with some hibernation feature hiding my folders?
I also add that the navigation is very slow: for sure the HD has some corrupted sectors...

Comment: Is there a question here?  You say you the drive is corrupt, so what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I think the driver is corrupt, nevertheless I can still see all the folders and files except those two. The question is: why? Is there a way to find my personal folder again?

Comment: An update won't corrupt the OS and don't use Linux to recover Windows, use WinRE; when WinRE fails the auto fix, on the blue screen with options, choose _Advanced_ → _Troubleshooting_ → _Command Prompt_. Determine the drive letter of the OS partition: `DiskPart` → `Lis vol` → `Exit` →`ChkDsk /OfflineScanAndFix D:` _(where `D:` is the OS drive letter)_ →  If BIOS: `Sfc /ScanNow && BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /FixBoot && BootRec /RebuildBCD` _(if UEFI: remove `&& BootRec /FixBoot`)_.

Comment: _Cont'd..._ If it still won't boot, download the Windows ISO from Microsoft → install on another PC → Save ISO → Either create a bootable USB from it using [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/en/) or extract the ISO to a folder → Use the `sources/install.wim`||`.esd` from the ISO and apply it to the OS partition via #2 [Apply Image] under [Imaging](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800) while booted to WinRE's Command Prompt. **Before Doing So:** _(`D:` is OS partition)_ `RoboCopy /E /Sec "D:\Windows\System32\config" "D:\config"` _(backs up the system Registry hives to merge later)_

Comment: Hello, I cant reach the winre autofix fail…it just keeps loading forever. I left it for about 8hours and no success…