# INACCESSIBLE BOOT DEVICE M.2 SATA

Tags: boot, ssd, sata, clone, nvme

I'm absolutely at my wits' end with this issue: I'm getting INACCESSIBLE BOOT DEVICE when cloning a M.2 SATA SSD to an NVMe one. I can always format and reinstall Windows but nevertheless, I would much prefer to clone this system and also I *want* to know if it can be done.

The computer is a HP Pavilion Power 15-cb0xx laptop. The source disk is a Sandisk SD8SNAT-256G SATA SSD connected to the only M.2 slot in the computer and I want to clone this Windows installation to a Western Digital SN750 SE NVMe SSD, also in the M.2 format. I use a USB adapter to use it as a destination disk. The laptop only has one M.2 slot and a SATA port, with a magnetic HDD attached. The BIOS hasn't got any options to change the storage mode to AHCI, RAID or whatever, but as I have inferred from Device Manager, it is running in AHCI mode. The SSD is in GPT Format and the computer is booting into UEFI mode, with Secure Boot disabled by default.

I've tried cloning it with CloneZilla and Acronis True Image with the very same result. BSOD at startup with INACCESSIBLE BOOT DEVICE message, which means that Windows couldn't locate the boot disk. The system is able to boot into Windows RE (although sometimes it's stuck on the black screen with the spinning circle) and correctly detects the Windows setup, even asking for the user account password.

Things I've already tried:

- Fiddling with the BCD, restoring the EFI GPT partition and its boot files. It wasn't likely the problem, but to start with something.
- Prior to cloning, installing NVMe drivers and editing the Windows Registry so that stornvme would be loaded at boot. Out of things to try, I also made every IAStor driver to be loaded at boot, to no avail. I also tried the "sc.exe config stornvme start= boot" command before cloning.
- Updating the Intel RST drivers to the maximum supported version before cloning. It also occurred to me that I could clone the M.2 SATA to a SATA attached disk and boot with that second disk with the NVMe connected in the M.2 slot to get Windows to recognise it. Guess what? If I clone the M.2 SATA to a SATA disk, I also get INACCESSIBLE BOOT DEVICE.

Is there anything more I can do? I don't know exactly what the dealbreaker here is, and the Windows Boot Log tells me that the stornvme driver is being loaded at each boot, but I can't get past the BSOD. I can't shake the feeling that I'm missing something or that there's other thing to try.

Comment: Third-party cloning utilities usually result in issues - Windows has natively supported imaging partitions since XP and would have alleviated the issue experienced, which I cover in [this](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800) answer. To resolve boot issues, please see Step 5 at the end of the linked to answer, with the commands listed executed from WinPE/WinRE. Secure Boot should always be enabled and CSM [Legacy] Mode disabled _(most, if not all, distros support Secure Boot and have wikis detailing how to create the EFI signing cert/key pair and how to register it in the UEFI firmware)_

Comment: Are you sure your M.2 port supports both SATA and NVMe?

Comment: I appreciate you both for taking time answering my question.

Ramhound yes, it's fully compatible with SATA and NVMe disks.

@JW0914 I rather think that the issue here is not from the cloning process, as I've done a sector-to-sector copy using CloneZilla, but something about Windows configuration. I didn't know I could use integrated Windows imaging tools, but I want to clone an entire disk and I don't know if cloning partition by partition would introduce issues here.

Comment: @Villodre The Windows [boot process](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/images/boot-sequence.png) is straightforward and your issue is either an issue with the UEFI/kernel NVME driver, I/O error with the NVME drive,  the BCD store _(if CSM Mode is disabled in the UEFI firmware - BIOS and UEFI are not the same things)_ or an incorrect EFI partition configuration - the latter two are almost always the reason for boot issues when using third-party cloning utilities, which I explain how to correct in the answer I linked to in my prior comment.

Comment: @Villodre _(Cont'd...)_ "_I rather think that the issue here is not from the cloning process, as I've done a sector-to-sector copy using CloneZilla, but something about Windows configuration_" There's a reason why there are [4,275](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=Windows%20cloning%20problem) results for "_Windows Cloning Problem_" and [3,112](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=Windows%20cloning%20issue) results for "_Windows Cloning Issue_", yet only ~100 for using Windows' native method _(I break the data down further in the previously linked to answer)_. Data speaks for itself.

Comment: @JW0914 I'll try your suggestion this evening and, if nothing else comes out of this, at least I'll learn to use DISM for imaging.