# "The boot loader did not load an operating system" for windows 10 hyper-v VM

Tags: boot, hyper-v, bootloader

I created a vhdx file from the c: drive from a lenovo P1G3 a while back and thought I had a working VM from it, but apparently not. Now when I try to boot the VM I get the "The boot loader did not load an operating system". The host is a win10 using the Hyper-V manager, and the VM is set to gen2 with the secure boot disabled. The vhdx file does not look to be corrupt, as I can attach and browse the files without any errors. I've tried the basic windows install iso --> "Startup Repair" but no luck. I've gone around in circles trying to use the bootrec, bcdboot, diskpart, etc... utilities per various superuser and similar forums, but I cannot figure out what is needed, and I'm pretty spun around wondering if I'm even starting in the right place.

[image]

Edit: adding more detail about the drive.  I only captured the C: volume of the drive, but have 2 unallocated volumes/partitions.  Here is what the drive looks like when the vhdx is mounted.
updated 2/24: now 7.11GB of free space per multiple `shrink` commands
[image]

Comment: You need to configure the boot partition if BIOS, EFI partition if UEFI, and the WinRE partition - Windows does not boot from `C:` _(see section "How do I configure system partitions on a new drive for applying an image?" at the end of [this](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800) answer)_

Comment: I'm still a little fuzzy.  the vhdx was captured from a win10 install with EFI/UEFI, I believe.   I'm not sure where exactly to start in the answer you linked

Comment: If only `C:` was captured for the VHD, create two more partitions on the virtual drive _([`shrink`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shrink) the `C:` partition)_ - EFI and WinRE - with the `DiskPart` commands required being in the last section of the linked-to answer _(technically a WinRE partition isn't needed in a virtual environment, but is recommended for convenience of use)_. If you captured both the `C:` partition and the EFI boot partition, boot WinPE/WinRE _(WinPE is the install ISO)_ and issue: `BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /RebuildBCD`

Comment: Ok, I think i'm following you now.  So, I should start under the section in the answer addressing the question "How do I configure system partitions on a new drive for applying an image?"?  I should only need to do steps 1 - "Use DiskPart:...", 2 - "Create WinRE partition:..." , and 3 - "Create boot partition:...".  Step 4 shouldn't be necessary b/c I already have the system drive?  Maybe step 5 if there are still boot issues.
Am I on the right track?

Comment: That's correct; you'll need to either shrink the `C:` partition first or enlarge the VHD by 1GB [1025MB RAW] if creating a WinRE partition, else only 128MB [132MB RAW] for the EFI boot partition. If shrinking, select the `C:` partition in `DiskPart` [`lis vol` → `sel vol #`], then `shrink desired=1025 minimum=1025` [with WinRE] or `shrink desired=132 minimum=132` [EFI partition only]. I can't recall if the `C:` partition can be shrunk while booted to Windows, so if not, you'll need to boot WinPE _(once the Windows installer's GUI loads, press `Shift`+`F10` to open a terminal)_

Comment: hmm, ok so it looks like the commands posted in that answer arent valid syntax anymore, getting a "The arguments specified for this command are not valid" for the "Cre Par Pri Offset=1024 Size=665 Id=27" statement.  Any chance you know of another answer that might have the same steps?  tia

Comment: They work fine - you're using the commands for BIOS, not UEFI. If you get stuck, you can reference the built-in man page via `help cre par pri` and if you issue `help` by itself, it'll walk you through the correct help command to issue.

Comment: ok, so i booted vm with the windows install iso, went to command prompt, diskpart, selected the disk, volume, and then tried "shrink desired=132 minimum=132" followed by "Cre Par Pri Offset=1024 Size=665 Id=de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac", but i'm getting a "not enough usable space" error?

Comment: Please use Google and refer to the [`DiskPart`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/diskpart) man page

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the version to 'Generation 1'.
You can do this only if you create the image from 'Hyper-V manager'. So open the Manager, -> New -> Virtual Machine.

In the dialog, the second step is to set the Generation. Try Generation 1, and it should work fine.