# Windows 10 install on USB disk

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive

I have created system backup of Windows 10 installation using Aomei Backupper and restored it external USB drive, however i cannot boot from external drive, how can i fix it?

Perhaps problem is that original disk was GPT and external USB is MBR?

Drive **E** and **G** are what become on my USB Drive after restoring.
[image]

**EDIT:**

Edited few more settings of BCD on boot partition of USB E:

[image]

[image]

Managed to get boot menu setup on **E:** and boot from that partition however upon selecting OS on drive **G:** i am getting error

[image]

With another boot option i created i managed to get little further to this screen after loading for a while.

[image]

Comment: "cannot boot from external drive" is not sufficient information to diagnose your problem. As I don't run Windows 10 myself I won't be able to help you unfortunately.

Comment: i updated my question, what OS you run?

Comment: I am running XP and Windows 7. As for your update there is still the information missing at which point of the boot process your boot process breaks. 
I never answer boot problems because there are too many variables. 
Microsoft makes installing Windows 10 on a USB drive difficult. Here is a tutorial in German language describing a possible way of installation:
https://www.wintotal.de/tipp/windows-10-auf-usb-stick-installieren/

Comment: @RomanToasov - Why are you asking us what OS we are running? It doesn’t appear you selected all of your partitions when you performed the initial backup. When you restored a GPT onto a drive the restoration of that backup would have also made it GPT

Comment: @Ramhound My understanding is the OP wants to boot from the USB backup.

Comment: @RomanToasov There are two ways to boot it: **(1)** Ensure its connected to the PC, boot to WinRE's command line: `BootRec FixMBR && BootRec /RebuildBCD` _(this will create a dual boot and you'll be prompted which to boot to when the Windows bootloader loads)_; **(2)** Configure an EFI boot partition on the external drive ([Steps 3 & 5](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800)) _(to boot to it, select the drive from the UEFI firmware boot menu, as this allows booting it without adding an entry to the BCD Store)_. General FYI: if it's a thumb drive, performance will be sub-par to horrible

Comment: i have external 2.5" over USB 3.0 port.
@Ramhound i ask for understanding because on every corner of internet consumers and marketing people are roaring "why you still use Windows 7" etc, and i do use Windows 7 myself that's why i want to run Windows 10 only when needed to run specific graphic apps that are Windows 10 only... 
P.S. Cannot install in separate partition on SSD also because i have problems with my 240GB SSD slow down when partitioned. Well actually i did not dedicate entire USB drive for the W10 only freed 100gb in beginning of the disk so it stay MBR.

Comment: @RomanToasov - Windows was not designed to be booted from a USB device.  One of the reasons the performance was so bad, is the same reason, Microsoft discontinued Windows 2 Go installation more than 3 years ago.

Comment: @DanielB Where are you getting that information from, as you can apply a Windows 10 WIM to an external drive and boot it without issue. Is it recommended to do so, no, as the performance isn't going to be there unless running it from a quality external SSD with a case designed as an efficient heat sink

Comment: @JW0914 You’re right, it does work. Maybe I remembered some information incorrectly.

Comment: @Ramhound could you point me to instruction on how to do it?

Comment: @RomanToasov - Do what exactly? Windows 2 Go?  Use Rufus way I know that works.

Comment: I used https://www.easeus.com/backup-recovery/backup-windows-10-to-usb-drive.html for Back Up Windows to USB External Drive. There are also steps available to boot from USB External Drive.