# Not able to create a system image - remote shared folder issue (Error code: 0x8078015B)

Tags: windows-10, backup, shared-folders, windows-backup, windows-system-image

I am trying to create a system image of my Windows 10 device on an external hard drive, but facing this "remote shared folder" issue. (0x8078015B)

[image: img_system_image_backup_failed]

The problem is - Backup is getting failed because of Windows Backup process is not able to access the shared folder, but I am not using any shared folder or any kind of network storage sort of thing.  So, feeling a bit confused about this.

As I don't know the exact reason, I have tried some possible solutions from here & there, such as disabling the Windows firewall, antivirus, non-Microsoft services, resetting network drivers but nothing seems to work.

Any solutions?

Note: Hard drive and data cable is working fine.

Comment: Windows Backup is old and lame. I suggest using a real backup product like [AOMEI Freeware](https://www.aomeitech.com/download.html#am-modal-downloads).

Comment: Do not use that backup method, as it's inefficient and creates more problems than it solves; instead, use Windows' native command-line method of creating a Windows Image [WIM] via `Dism`, which I cover [here](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800). Any third-party solution is not going to be as efficient since all lack the compression capabilities and parity WIMs benefit from, combined with the fact there is zero purpose to a partition-level/disk-level image _(contains offset, alignment, block size, etc.)_ on Windows since NTFS has been the default filesystem for two decades.