# Cloning/copying a complete PC

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, cloning

My home has a high end Home Theater controlled by a small PC with two separate drives (C and D). I will be selling the house some time in the near future (I am 83 years old). I designed the theater and wrote all the code to control and integrate the various components.

I would like to put the whole system on a bootable thumb drive So the purchaser has the ability to restore the entire system if needed. I would like the new user to be able to insert the thumb drive have it boot and restore both the C and D drives .  Is this possible?  If so what software can do it? The system is Windows 10, the drives are in FAT format with a Master boot record on C.

Comment: Please see [this](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800) answer for how to do so natively in Windows via `Dism /Capture-Image` and `Dism /Apply-Image`

Comment: For the bootable USB, you'd create a WinPE USB drive _(easiest way is to use Microsoft's Media Creation Tool, deleting `sources\install.<esd||wim>`)_ and a WinPE `.cmd` script that prompts the user to select the drive and partition(s) to apply the WIM to _(I created a script to do so a while back, but forgot to modify it to work in WinPE, and can paste a link later today when I'm on my laptop)_. The script, after modifying slightly to work in WinPE, would then be added to WinPE's `boot.wim` and WinPE would be configured to run the script upon boot via one of two files WinPE loads at boot.

Comment: It might be easier to make a Virtual Machine that does all these functions. Then you have a system that does what you want and is one file that you can load on any computer.. It might then also be possible to set Windows to start the VM Software, and boot into a VM.