# After using Clonezilla on a Surface Pro 7+ BitLocker is triggered

Tags: windows-11, clonezilla, microsoft-surface-pro

I do not have BitLocker activated, I have never even used it.

To be able to start Clonezilla from a USB stick, I disable Secure Boot.
After cloning a Surface Pro 7+ running Windows 11, trying to start Windows results in a blue screen showing

```
BitLocker
You need to enter your recovery key because Secure Boot has been disabled
Enter your recovery key to be able to use the computer again
```

Even when I enable Secure Boot again, it keeps telling me this.
I have tried it with different devices, and it's always the same.

Comment: "Why is that and how do I resolve that?" - It's your BitLocker Recover key, without it, your device is encrypted and cannot boot into Windows. Thankfully, by default on Microsoft Surface devices, your BitLocker Recovery key is automatically stored connected your Microsoft Account.  BitLocker is enabled by default on all Microsoft Surface products unless explicitly disabled by the customer. You won't be able to bypass the prompt, so if for some reason you don't have the BitLocker Recovery key you will have to reinstall Windows. Even if you were to restore the image the recovery key would be req

Comment: BTW, there is no need to use software requiring Secure Boot be disabled to clone or image a drive. Macrium Reflect rescue media, and many other imaging USB boot tools, can b used with Secure Boot enabled.

Comment: But I am not using BitLocker nor do I want to.

Comment: And no, it does not store it if you remove the online account.

Comment: Windows [natively](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800) supports imaging partitions via `Dism`, which is included in WinPE/WinRE and the OS