# What is the directory of the bcd file?

Tags: boot, bcd

According to my research, I found that the directory of `BCD` for BIOS is `System Reserved partition\boot\BCD`, but in my system there is a similar directory [`EFI\boot\`] which does not contain the `BCD` file.

Why does the said directory and `BCD` do not exist for me?

Answer (score 2):

The `BCD` Store file provides a store used to describe boot applications and settings.

EFI boot still has a `BCD` Store file, located in in the same place, just in a different top-end hierarchy *(without a `BCD` Store file, Windows can't boot)*:

- **BIOS:** `\\<boot partition>\boot\BCD`
- **EFI:** `\\<efi partition>\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\BCD` 
  `\\<efi partition>\EFI\Microsoft\Recovery\BCD`

The `BCD` Store file is managed with three utilities: [`BcdEdit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/bcdedit), [`BcdBoot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bcdboot-command-line-options-techref-di), and [`BootRec`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-bootrec-exe-in-the-windows-re-to-troubleshoot-startup-issues-902ebb04-daa3-4f90-579f-0fbf51f7dd5d)

---

### [Overview of Boot Options in Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/boot-options-in-windows)

> [Boot Configuration Data [BCD] Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/boot-options-in-windows#boot-configuration-data):
>
> Windows boot options are stored in the Boot Configuration Data [`BCD`] store on BIOS-based and EFI-based computers.
>
> BCD provides a common, firmware-independent boot option interface, is more secure than previous boot option storage configurations, and lets Administrators assign rights for managing boot options; BCD is available at run time and during all phases of system setup.
>
> You can manage BCD remotely and manage BCD when the system boots from media other than the media on which the `BCD` store resides. This feature can be used for debugging and troubleshooting, especially when a `BCD` store must be restored while running Startup Repair, from USB-based storage media, or even remotely.
>
> The `BCD` store, with its object-and-element architecture, uses GUIDs and names such as `default` to identify boot-related applications, and BCD includes its own set of boot options. For more information about these boot options, see: 
>  [BCD Boot Options Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/bcd-boot-options-reference)

---

### [BCD System Store Settings for UEFI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bcd-system-store-settings-for-uefi)

> [Windows Boot Loader Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bcd-system-store-settings-for-uefi#windows-boot-loader-settings):
>
> A `BCD` store has at least one instance, and optionally multiple instances, of the Windows Boot Loader, with a separate BCD object representing each instance. Each instance loads one of the installed versions of Windows that has a configuration the object's elements have specified. Each Windows Boot Loader object has its own identifier, and the object's `device` and `path` settings indicate the correct partition and boot application.
>
> BCD-template for a single Windows Boot Loader object:
>
> ```ini
> ## Windows Boot Loader
>
> identifier              {9f25ee7a-e7b7-11db-94b5-f7e662935912}
> device                  partition=C:
> path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi
> description             Microsoft Windows Server
> locale                  en-US
> inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
> osdevice                partition=C:
> systemroot              \Windows
> ```
>
> The identifier for this Windows Boot Loader is as follows, and you can use this GUID on your system, or let the `BCDEdit` tool generate a new GUID for you: 
>  `{9f25ee7a-e7b7-11db-94b5-f7e662935912}`
>
> To simplify `BCDEdit` commands, you can specify one of the Windows Boot Loaders in the `BCD` system store as the default loader, then use the standard identifier `{default}` in place of the full GUID.
>
> This example specifies the Windows Boot Loader for EFI as the default boot loader, and assumes it uses the identifier GUID from BCD-template:
>
> ```
> Bcdedit /default {9f25ee7a-e7b7-11db-94b5-f7e662935912}
> ```

Comment: Why can't I see the file and directory you mention in the system reserved partition?

Comment: @SEPEHR On EFI boot? It's not accessible from within the OS - if you boot to WinPE/WinRE and open a terminal, you can see the files. I thought it used to be possible to mount the EFI partition via `diskpart` and give yourself read permissions, but on Windows 11, that's no longer possible AFAIK. When I have time later today or tomorrow, I'll boot to WinRE and if I can't do screenshots, I'll list the hierarchy via `dir` and post within a code box

Comment: I'm looking for the bcd file that corresponds to the drive that the OS failed to boot onto .
I currently have booted my system to another drive

Comment: @SEPEHR It would be in the EFI partition or if using separate EFI partitions, in the EFI partition for the OS that failed to boot - if it doesn't exist, it can be rebuilt automatically in WinRE via `BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /RebuildBCD` or manually via `BcdEdit` or `BcdBoot` _(see Step #5 at the bottom of [this](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800) answer)_ - man pages for all are linked above.