# Can I copy paste 200GB+ from one disk to another in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-transfer

I'm trying to make a backup of my 1TB SSD (80%) to a 1TB HDD, which is empty.

To do so, I'm trying to move 200GB from one to another, so I can format / recover (I don’t know yet), installing Ubuntu Linux instead of Windows 10, but keeping my `./users/me` data in the `E:` disk with Windows 10.

What would be the proper way to copy paste this data? Why not a <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>?

Comment: I’ll just return this question: Why do you think you need a “proper way”? Maybe you want to verify the transfer? Or you want to be able to resume it if interrupted? Maybe performance is important, and/or you heard Explorer is slow in copying data?

Comment: it is not clear from your question if you want to have a full backup (including the OS) of your disk on the new ssd. Copy - paste will work for your personal files, but it won't work for the OS: you'll need to make a [disk cloning](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_cloning) for that, using something like [clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/)

Comment: Normal Cppy - paste from one ssd to the other of 200GB, on a SATA SSD should take about 7 - 20 Minutes (calculating 200 - 500 MB / sec of transfer speed)

Comment: Copying large volumes of files will always be faster via `robocopy`, not through the GUI, and copying files is a very inefficient way of creating a backup. Backups in Windows are done via [capturing WIMs](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800)

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered [robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) in command prompt, which is good for backup handling large amount of data.

```
robocopy source destination /E /ZB /COPYALL /R:5 /W:5
```

Comment: FYI: `/zb` requires an admin terminal, else it will fail. While this answer will do what the OP is technically asking, copying files is a very inefficient way of creating a backup; backups in Windows are done via [capturing WIMs](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800)