# Windows System Image Restore mixes up drives

Tags: windows, partitioning, recovery

So to upgrade my internal SSD, I created a system image, swapped the drive (new one is larger) and booted from an USB drive. But for some reasons one of my external drives seems to be part of the system image (when I tell the wizard to skip restoring it, the restoration fails with an appropriate error message), I am not really sure why.

But if I leave the the external drive connected and don't skip it, the recovery does not fail.

After the recovery I am unable to boot my PC though, and by inspecting the contents of the external drive and the partition table of the internal drive I realized that the recovery

**mixes up the drives and restores the content of the external drive on my internal SSD and vice versa**

How can I fix this? Do I need to make sure all drives are connected to the exact USB ports that they were connected to when I created the image? Does anybody know why the external drive is included in the image anyways (maybe because I set it up as a recovery drive or something?)

Comment: While I don't know how to correct that issue since I don't use this method due to this and other inefficiencies, a better, more efficient way is to [capture a WIM](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800) of the partition(s), then apply the WIM(s) to the new drive in WinPE/WinRE. Instead of building a GUI tool that leverages WIMs and all their benefits _(such as parity through hash verification and no reliance on external files)_, Microsoft chose user convenience over efficiency _(a WIM of the OS partition can only be captured from WinPE/WinRE, versus using VSS to copy to a VHD image with WIB)_

Comment: How did you create the system image ?