# Troubleshooting New PC Build: Successful Boot with Old SSD but Blue Screen on chkdsk and Intel Chipset Driver Installation Issue

Tags: drivers, windows-11, bsod, kernel, chkdsk

I built a new computer and took SSD with Windows from old PC and put it into new PC (reason of doing this is I have tons of work-related apps that I would have to download & reinstall & relicense which would take tremendous amount of time and anyway some of the projects would not work).

I booted my new PC and everything works quite good.

After BIOS update, Windows Update and drivers update, I ran sfc /scannow, and DISM commands, to check if everything is okay, and I got no errors/corruptions. My Windows is running correctly.

I even ran CPU stress test, GPU stress test, and RAM Memory Tests and everything passed correctly. I also played the games. I am having no performance or stability issues, and PC is much faster than the older.

**Only problem I have** is when running chkdsk as a last step of checking if everything is OK, and I get the Blue Screen with error **KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILED**. **But I can boot normally into Windows when I skip the chkdsk, and use PC as usual**.

**Also, I have kind of trouble installing Intel Chipset Driver**. I have MSI motherboard, which has MSI Center App that can detect driver updates and update drivers. This app says that I have old Intel Chipset Driver version, but when installing it by the app, it fails to install. When I try to download it manually from MSI website and install it, it fails as it says "Feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable.".

In fact, running the installer normally gets me into Unknown Error. I found out that I have to End Task for Windows Installer in Task Manager to run installation properly. Then I get the "Feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable." error.

There is a path to the Packagecache.msi in C:/ProgramData/Package Cache/. This folder that it tries to find, I dont have in the actual folder. This folder I believe represents the package of the "current" Intel Chipset Driver, but I dont understand why installing newer Intel Chipset Driver requires package of the older version.

I believe that this might be registry related and might be fixed by deleting some registry.

Also, fixing Intel Chipset Driver might eventually fix chkdsk, maybe not.

**NOTE:** On the SSD in my old PC I had dual-boot (Linux) which was installed on this SSD. I had a look into Windows Partition Manager, and that the partitions separated for the Linux still were there, but they were not "recognized" (there was only size amount, but not parition type text nor File System type text and Status text, which is present in other partitions of the drive). So I was wondering that I might clean those parititons and add them to the Windows partition and try running chkdsk after that.

**What I tried:**
Reinstalling Windows 11 using Installation media tools and choosing option Keep personal data, apps & settings. (So that I remain all my Apps & SW & files).

Finding the version of Packagecachex64 that Intel Chipset Driver installer requires, did not find it (at least on reliable websites like Intel, MSI)

When I get home, I can send some LOG files that might be needed to provide more info, and tell you current Intel Chipset Driver verison & version that I try to install.

My specs:
Windows 11
MSI PRO Z790-S Wifi
Intel Core i5-14500
NVidia GeForce RTX 3060Ti by MSI
Kingston Fury Beast 1x32GB DDR5
SSD is Transcend MTE250S

Comment: Chipset drivers normally can't be updated after the fact, as chipset drivers _must_ be installed prior to any other drivers, software, or Windows Updates immediately upon exiting OOBE before anything else is done on the machine. For this specifically, I would do a clean install of Windows, installing only the updated chipset drivers, not the original, as soon as OOBE is exited and at the desktop. For the Kernel error, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x139--kernel-security-check-failure) for the cause - a clean install would also fix this

Comment: @JW0914 I assume that the system installed either the older version of Intel Chipset Driver, or there is installed the correct version but the system "thinks" there is still installed the older version (maybe due to some registry).

Is there a way to avoid this even when doing clean install, so I dont run into the same issue?

Comment: If the updated chipset driver installer issue occurs with a clean install, the issue is the installer, but that's rare for an OEM driver supplied via their support site since they're extensively tested before provided for end user use. I've never come across an OEM offering an "updated" chipset driver and trying to update the current chipset drivers, as that's simply not how chipset drivers work AFAIK _(my understanding could very well be wrong, as my understanding is chipset drivers shouldn't be installed once other drivers, software, or Windows Updates have been installed)_

Comment: _(Cont'd...)_ Since it's not possible to install chipset drivers within a VM, the only way to know would be to clean install Windows on the physical machine - to preserve your current OS and applications/data, I'd recommend testing by either clean installing Windows to another hard drive, or if that's not possible, [capturing a WIM](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800) of your current OS partition, which creates a backup image you can restore from applying the WIM to the formatted OS partition _(I'd recommend capturing a WIM regardless)_

Comment: Yeah, but you can check that MSI provides [driver installer](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/PRO-Z790-S-WIFI/support#driver) as well as other MB manufacturers.

On the internet I have read that this driver actually just names other components, which you can see in Device Manager. Dont know if thats true tho.

Also I forgot to mention, I had problem with first boot (I had black screen), I ordered 12th gen i3 so I can do BIOS update as I thought that Im getting black screen because i5 needed it to work.

But I found out all I needed was connect DisplayPort to GPU port instead of MB port.

Comment: CONTINUE: So in the end, I might boot into BIOS with i5 (I also had black screen with i3 until I found out I was plugging DisplayPort into MB port instead of GPU).

The question is - Do you think that BIOS Update & first boot into Windows Login Screen was with i3, that it might install older driver for i3, which now cant be reinstalled when trying to upgrade chipset driver for newer i5, that however might be compatible with this older driver?

Comment: While hardware abstraction has improved alot in windows, i think its still a terrible idea to use an old windows install from different hardware on new hardware. It looks like you're going to rely on this setup for important things. Save yourself the current (and future !) headaches and do a clean install.

Comment: Yeah, I decided to backup my Apps, SW & Data by dragging & droping them on Backup HDD. I backed up folders from Documents, Program Files, Program Files (x86), ProgramData and %appdata%. Hopefully the apps will work when I put them back from HDD to new Windows.