# Moving Windows from SATA SSD to M2 RAID

Tags: windows-10, raid, windows-backup, windows-restore

I have a Windows 10 machine with Auros Z390 Pro mainbard, SATA SSD system disk and RAID0 with two M2 disks:

[image]

How do I move my system to RAID?

I created system image:

[image]

and a recovery DVD.

Also I have Intel RST driver consisting with the following files:

```
ReadMe.txt
SetupRST.exe
SetupRST.zip
```

What do I do next?

Do I simply unplug system drive, boot from recovery DVD and try to restore my system to the RAID?

**EDIT1**

Looks like recovery DVD does not allow to do that, so I need a tool like Northon Ghost, right?

What will happen if I copy my system disk as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640259/how-can-i-easily-clone-my-entire-system) with a command like

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb status=progress
```

?

Comment: From WinPE/WinRE, [capture a WIM](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800) of the EFI, OS, and WinRE partitions, then apply each WIM to each respective partition once RAID is configured _(partition creation steps are covered at the very bottom of the linked to answer)_

Comment: Generally not recommended to do what you want. OSes are better left out of RAID or similar. The mentions of "DVD" and "Norton Ghost" suggest you're out of your dept and living in a bygone era.